# Why do we need break after case statements?

Tags: java, switch-statement, case, language-design, break

Why doesn't the compiler automatically put break statements after each code block in the switch? Is it for historical reasons? When would you want multiple code blocks to execute?

Comment: [Made an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710300/why-do-we-need-break-after-case-statements/52238570#52238570) about JDK-12 and switch labels reformed to not mandate `break`.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Sometimes it is helpful to have multiple cases associated with the same code block, such as

```
case 'A':
case 'B':
case 'C':
    doSomething();
    break;

case 'D':
case 'E':
    doSomethingElse();
    break;
```

etc. Just an example.

In my experience, usually it is bad style to "fall through" and have multiple blocks of code execute for one case, but there may be uses for it in some situations.

Comment: Just always add a comment along the lines `// Intentional fallthrough.` when you omit a break.  It's not so much a bad style as "easy to forget a break accidentally" in my opinion.  P.S. Of course not in simple cases as in the answer itself.

Comment: @doublep - I agree. In my opinion, I'd avoid it if possible but if it makes sense then make sure it is very clear what you are doing.

Comment: @doublep: I'd not bother with the comment if the multiple `case` s are stacked together that way. If there's code in between them then yes, the comment is probably merited.

Comment: I imagine a language where you can declare multiple cases within one `case`, like so: `case 'A','B','C':  doSomething(); case 'D','E': doSomethingElse();`, without needing a break between cases. Pascal could do that: "The case statement compares the value of ordinal expression to each selector, which can be a constant, a subrange, or a list of them separated by commas." (http://wiki.freepascal.org/Case)

Comment: orrible java syntax

Answer (score 34):

[Historically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement), it's because the `case` was essentially defining a `label`, also known as the [target point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Label_%28programming_language%29) of a `goto` call.  The switch statement and its associated cases really just represent a multiway branch with multiple potential entry points into a stream of code.

All that said, it has been noted a nearly infinite number of times that `break` is almost always the default behavior that you'd rather have at the end of every case.

Answer (score 32):

Java comes from C and that is the syntax from C.

There are times where you want multiple case statements to just have one execution path.
Below is a sample that will tell you how many days in a month.

```
class SwitchDemo2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int month = 2;
        int year = 2000;
        int numDays = 0;

        switch (month) {
            case 1:
            case 3:
            case 5:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 10:
            case 12:
                numDays = 31;
                break;
            case 4:
            case 6:
            case 9:
            case 11:
                numDays = 30;
                break;
            case 2:
                if ( ((year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 100 == 0))
                     || (year % 400 == 0) )
                    numDays = 29;
                else
                    numDays = 28;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid month.");
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("Number of Days = " + numDays);
    }
}
```

Comment: Someone aimed for the up arrow and missed?  Or maybe they had a beef with your brace style or indentation...

Comment: Dunno, so have a +1 from me.  This is an example where the fall-through helps, though I really wish Java had picked a more modern case statement.  Cobol's EVALUATE-WHEN-OTHERWISE is far more powerful, and *predates* Java.  Scala's match expression is a modern example of what could be done.

Comment: My students would be publicly flogged for doing this.  It's coyote ugly.

Comment: @ncmathsadist It illustrates a point on one way of doing something. I do not disagree that this example is probably extreme. But it is a real world example, which I believe helps people comprehend a concept.

Answer (score 14):

You can do all sorts of interesting things with case fall-through.

For example, lets say you want to do a particular action for all cases, but in a certain case you want to do that action plus something else.  Using a switch statement with fall-through would make it quite easy.

```
switch (someValue)
{
    case extendedActionValue:
        // do extended action here, falls through to normal action
    case normalActionValue:
    case otherNormalActionValue:
        // do normal action here
        break;
}
```

Of course, it is easy to forget the `break` statement at the end of a case and cause unexpected behavior.  Good compilers will warn you when you omit the break statement.

Comment: Can switch/case be used on strings in Java?

Comment: @Steve: Oops, I guess not at the moment.  According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java/338230#338230, strings will be allowed in a future version of Java.  (I currently do most of my programming in C#, which does allow strings in switch statements.)  I've edited the answer to remove the misleading quotes.

Comment: @ZachJohnson, much later, Java 7 does allow switch on Strings.

Answer (score 9):

The `break` after switch `case`s is used to avoid the fallthrough in the switch statements. Though interestingly this now can be achieved through the newly formed switch labels as implemented via [JEP-325](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/325).

With these changes, the `break` with every  switch `case` can be avoided as demonstrated further :-

```
public class SwitchExpressionsNoFallThrough {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value = scanner.nextInt();
        /*
         * Before JEP-325
         */
        switch (value) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("one");
            case 2:
                System.out.println("two");
            default:
                System.out.println("many");
        }

        /*
         * After JEP-325
         */
        switch (value) {
            case 1 ->System.out.println("one");
            case 2 ->System.out.println("two");
            default ->System.out.println("many");
        }
    }
}
```

On [executing the above code with JDK-12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232681/compile-a-jdk12-preview-feature-with-maven), the *comparative output* could be seen as

```
//input
1
// output from the implementation before JEP-325
one
two
many
// output from the implementation after JEP-325
one
```

and

```
//input
2
// output from the implementation before JEP-325
two
many
// output from the implementation after JEP-325
two
```

and of course the thing unchanged

```
// input
3
many // default case match
many // branches to 'default' as well
```

Answer (score 7):

> Why doesn't the compiler automatically put break statements after each code block in the switch?

Leaving aside the *good* desire to be able to use the identical block for several cases (which could be special-cased)...

> Is it for historical reasons? When would you want multiple code blocks to execute?

It's mainly for compatibility with C, and is arguably an ancient hack from the days of old when `goto` keywords roamed the earth. It *does* enable some amazing things, of course, such as [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffs_device), but whether that's a point in its favor or against is… argumentative at best.

Answer (score 4):

So you do not have to repeat code if you need several cases to do the same thing:

```
case THIS:
case THAT:
{
    code;
    break;
}
```

Or you can do things like :

```
case THIS:
{
   do this;
}
case THAT:
{
   do that;
}
```

In a cascade fashion.

Really bug/confusion prone, if you ask me.

Comment: does that run both `do this` and `do that` for this but just `do that` for that?

Comment: just read the docs.  That's awful!  What an easy way to write bugs!

Answer (score 4):

As far as the historical record goes, Tony Hoare invented the case statement in the 1960s, during the "structured programming" revolution.  Tony's case statement supported multiple labels per case and automatic exit with no stinking `break` statements.  The requirement for an explicit `break` was something that came out of the BCPL/B/C line.  Dennis Ritchie writes (in ACM HOPL-II):

> For example, the endcase that escapes from a BCPL switchon statement was not present in the language
>   when we learned it in the 1960s, and so the overloading of the break keyword to escape
>   from the B and C switch statement owes to divergent evolution rather than conscious change.

I haven't been able to find any historical writings about BCPL, but Ritchie's comment suggests that the `break` was more or less a historical accident.  BCPL later fixed the problem, but perhaps Ritchie and Thompson were too busy inventing Unix to be bothered with such a detail :-)

Comment: This should get more votes. Apparently the OP already knew omitting `break` allows "multiple code blocks to execute", and is more concerned with the motivation of this design choice. Others mentioned the well-known heritage from C to Java, and this answer pushed the research even further to pre-C days. I wish we had this (though very primitive) pattern matching from the very start.

Answer (score 3):

Java is derived from C, whose heritage includes a technique known as [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) .
It's an optimization that relies on the fact that control falls through from one case to the next, in the absence of a `break;` statement. By the time C was standardized, there was plenty of code like that "in the wild", and it would have been counterproductive to change the language to break such constructions.

Answer (score 3):

As people said before, it is to allow fall-through and it is not a mistake, it is a feature. 
If too many `break` statements annoy you, you can easily get rid of them by using `return` statements instead. This is actually a good practice, because your methods should be as small as possible (for the sake of readability and maintainability), so a `switch` statement is already big enough for a method, hence, a good method should not contain anything else, this is an example:

```
public class SwitchTester{
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SwitchTester.class);
    public static void main(String[] args){
        log.info(monthsOfTheSeason(Season.WINTER));
        log.info(monthsOfTheSeason(Season.SPRING));
        log.info(monthsOfTheSeason(Season.SUMMER));
        log.info(monthsOfTheSeason(Season.AUTUMN));
    }

    enum Season{WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, AUTUMN};

    static String monthsOfTheSeason(Season season){
        switch(season){
            case WINTER:
                return "Dec, Jan, Feb";
            case SPRING:
                return "Mar, Apr, May";
            case SUMMER:
                return "Jun, Jul, Aug";
            case AUTUMN:
                return "Sep, Oct, Nov";
            default:
                //actually a NullPointerException will be thrown before reaching this
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Season must not be null");
        }        
    }
}
```

The execution prints:

```
12:37:25.760 [main] INFO lang.SwitchTester - Dec, Jan, Feb
12:37:25.762 [main] INFO lang.SwitchTester - Mar, Apr, May
12:37:25.762 [main] INFO lang.SwitchTester - Jun, Jul, Aug
12:37:25.762 [main] INFO lang.SwitchTester - Sep, Oct, Nov
```

as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question but actually I ran into using the case without break statement today. Not using break is actually very useful when you need to combine different functions in sequence.

e.g. using http response codes to authenticate user with time token

server response code 401 - token is outdated -> regenerate token and log user in.
server response code 200 - token is OK -> log user in.

in case statements:

```
case 404:
case 500:
        {
            Log.v("Server responses","Unable to respond due to server error");
            break;
        }
        case 401:
        {
             //regenerate token
        }
        case 200:
        {
            // log in user
            break;
        }
```

Using this you do not need to call log in user function for 401 response because when the token is regenerated, the runtime jumps into the case 200.

Answer (score 0):

Not having an automatic break added by the compiler makes it possible to use a switch/case to test for conditions like `1 <= a <= 3` by removing the break statement from 1 and 2.

```
switch(a) {
  case 1: //I'm between 1 and 3
  case 2: //I'm between 1 and 3
  case 3: //I'm between 1 and 3
          break;
}
```

Comment: Yecch. I totally hate this.

Answer (score 0):

because there are situations where you want to flow through the first block for example to avoid writing the same code in multiple blocks but still be able to divide them for mroe control. There are also a ton of other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can makes easily to separate other type of number, month, count.
This is better then if in this case;

```
public static void spanishNumbers(String span){

    span = span.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
    switch (span){
     case "1":    
     case "jan":  System.out.println("uno"); break;    
     case "2":      
     case "feb":  System.out.println("dos"); break;    
     case "3":     
     case "mar":  System.out.println("tres"); break;   
     case "4":   
     case "apr":  System.out.println("cuatro"); break;
     case "5":    
     case "may":  System.out.println("cinco"); break;
     case "6":     
     case "jun":  System.out.println("seis"); break;
     case "7":    
     case "jul":  System.out.println("seite"); break;
     case "8":    
     case "aug":  System.out.println("ocho"); break;
     case "9":   
     case "sep":  System.out.println("nueve"); break;
     case "10":    
     case "oct": System.out.println("diez"); break;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am now working on project where I am in need of `break` in my switch statement otherwise the code won't work. Bear with me and I will give you a good example of why you need `break` in your switch statement.

Imagine you have three states, one that waits for the user to enter a number, the second to calculate it and the third to print the sum.

In that case you have:

1. **State1** - Wait for user to enter a number
2. **State2** - Print the sum
3. **state3** - Calculate the sum

Looking at the states, you would want the order of exaction to start on **state1**, then **state3** and finally **state2**. Otherwise we will only print users input without calculating the sum. Just to clarify it again, we wait for the user to enter a value, then calculate the sum and prints the sum.

Here is an example code:

```
while(1){
    switch(state){
      case state1:
        // Wait for user input code
        state = state3; // Jump to state3
        break;
      case state2:
        //Print the sum code
        state = state3; // Jump to state3;
      case state3:
        // Calculate the sum code
        state = wait; // Jump to state1
        break;
    }
}
```

If we don't use `break`, it will execute in this order, **state1**, **state2** and **state3**. But using `break`, we avoid this scenario, and can order in the right procedure which is to begin with state1, then state3 and last but not least state2.

Answer (score -1):

Exactly, because with some clever placement you can execute blocks in cascade.