# Update or change images in View during runtime

Tags: java, android

I have a little problem updating UI in OnClick Event.

When I do this:

```
case R.id.radStripMiningCoal :
    {    
        LinearLayout testLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layouttest);
        LinearLayout layout3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);
        LinearLayout layout4 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout3);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.recomended);
        LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.basic);


        int origWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(origWidth,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout2.setLayoutParams(params);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);
        testLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        layout3.setLayoutParams(params);
        layout4.setLayoutParams(params);

        stripminingcoal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        VSLists.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Next.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();

            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.multispd1), 5000);
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img1), 5000);
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shocktubecluster1), 5000);
            animation.setOneShot(false);

            ImageView imageAnim =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBasicIS);           
            imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);            
            animation.start();

            AnimationDrawable animation2 = new AnimationDrawable();
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unidelaysp), 5000);
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.trunkline), 5000);                
            animation2.setOneShot(false);

            ImageView imageAnim2 =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRecomendedIS);         
            imageAnim2.setBackgroundDrawable(animation2);             
            animation2.start();

            AnimationDrawable animation3 = new AnimationDrawable();

            animation3.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.leadin2), 5000);  
            animation3.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tubestarter),5000);
            animation3.setOneShot(false);
            ImageView imageAnim3 =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRecomendedBSS);            
            imageAnim3.setBackgroundDrawable(animation3);           
            animation3.start();

            txtBasicIS.setText("Shock Tube Multi SPD / Detonating Cord / Cluster");   
            txtRecomendedIS.setText("Shock Tube Uni-Delay SP / Trunkline");
            txtRecomendedBSS.setText("Lead-In Line / Electric Shock Tube Starter");
```

Everything updates and displays fine.
But s soon as I do the same code in a different on "case" it does not update the images to the new images:

```
    case R.id.radNarrowReefGold:
    {
        LinearLayout testLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layouttest);
        LinearLayout layout3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);
        LinearLayout layout4 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout3);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.recomended);
        LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.basic);


        int origWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(origWidth,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout2.setLayoutParams(params);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);
        testLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        layout3.setLayoutParams(params);
        layout4.setLayoutParams(params);

        stripminingcoal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        VSLists.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Next.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();

            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.udlp3), 5000);
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.udlp6), 5000);
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.trunkline), 5000);
            animation.setOneShot(false);

            ImageView imageAnim =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBasicIS);           
            imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);            
            animation.start();

            AnimationDrawable animation2 = new AnimationDrawable();
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.udlp3vivid), 5000);
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.udlp6vivid), 5000);   
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.trunkline), 5000);                
            animation2.setOneShot(false);

            ImageView imageAnim2 =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRecomendedIS);         
            imageAnim2.setBackgroundDrawable(animation2);             
            animation2.start();

            AnimationDrawable animation3 = new AnimationDrawable();

            animation3.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.leadin2), 5000);  
            animation3.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tubestarter),5000);
            animation3.setOneShot(false);
            ImageView imageAnim3 =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRecomendedBSS);            
            imageAnim3.setBackgroundDrawable(animation3);           
            animation3.start();

            txtBasicIS.setText("Uni-Delay LP (3) / Uni-Delay LP (6) / Trunkline");   
            txtRecomendedIS.setText("Shock Tube Uni-Delay SP / Trunkline");
            txtRecomendedBSS.setText("Lead-In Line / Electric Shock Tube Starter"); 
    }
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

The textViews does not change either.

Thanks in advance.
Patrick

Comment: don't you just miss the `break;` statements from the end of the `case` blocks?

Comment: Thanks. that was it... stupid rookie mistake!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need break after case statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710300/why-do-we-need-break-after-case-statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the missing "break;" statement in your switch case structure.

You can test this using the following small snippets i wrote on the fly. If you remove the break; statement, you could not swicth the text to MESSI, it shows only RONALDO. In other words, the logic is broken.

If the "break;" is there, you can switch between MESSI and RONALDO.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

TextView myText;
private Button b1;
private Button b2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myText = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        b1 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.buttonMessi);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);

        b2 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.buttonRonaldo);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonMessi:
            myText.setText("MESSI");
          break;
        case R.id.buttonRonaldo:
            myText.setText("RONALDO");
          break;
      }

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMessi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:text="Messi" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonRonaldo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:text="Ronaldo" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: *faceDesk* Such a stupid rookie mistake! thanks a mill for the pointer!

Comment: it happens all the time, that's what makes coding so much fun :)

Comment: Just a question. how can I go by changing Imageview Source without the animation setting. Eg. img.SetImageResource(R.drawable.img);?

Comment: yes, use img.SetImageResource(R.drawable.img); if this does not work. Try to add img.SetImageResource(0); before the previous line. This sorts of like reset the drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add img.SetImageResource(0); before the previous line.
It worked kudos to you