# Why "switch" in java does check more cases than required?

Tags: java, switch-statement, break

I already searched in stackoverflow for reasons concerning the question, why switch does not break after having found a matching case.

For example, I have written some code which simulates a dice. For every throw, I count up for statistical reasons (one, ... = int).

```
switch (actualThrow) {
case (1): one++; 
case (2): two++; 
case (3): three++; 
case (4): four++;
case (5): five++; 
case (6): six++; 
}
```

I **DO** know, that case(3)-case(6) will be checked, if my throw was a 3 ([Why do we need break after case statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710300/why-do-we-need-break-after-case-statements)) and it will be prevented by inserting `break;`, but I want to ***understand***, why obviously the following cases seem to be checked, but execute, although the condition is not fulfilled.

Comment: The various cases in a switch *fall through* until the switch ends or they reach a break. The condition check only determines the *starting* case.

Comment: So you understand that you need `break`s but want to know why the subsequent cases are executed? I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question.

Comment: i understand, that subsequents are executed, so i need `break`s. i do not understand, WHY the checking fails.

Comment: Because there is no checking after the jump to the matching case. The cases are merely entry points.

Comment: Voting to reopen. None of the answers in the duplicate cite the JLS that explains why this is the case.

Comment: It's not checking anymore and it's not failing.  It looks for the first label that matches your `actualThrow` and continues until it finds the end of statement (for the switch statement) or a `break;`.  That's the behavior given to a switch statement.

Comment: Because (1): there can be a "default" that needs to be executed; (2): there can be more than one case per block (ie, case 1: case 2: case 3: lowroll++;); and, (default): it is what it is.

Comment: @michael_n I disagree with part (1) of your comment.  I don't think the fallthrough is simply because there *might* be a `default:` label.  Also, a `default:` statement can be placed at the top, it's simply convention we put it at the bottom.

Comment: @BLaZuRE I agree with you; I frankly don't completely understand what the questioner is really looking for, other than some way to better understand why it is the way it is; ie, more practical examples rather than a spec clarification.

Comment: @BLaZuRE based on the accepted answer, sounds like my case #2 is really what was needed to clarify the situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine this scenario:

```
switch(trafficLight.state) {
    case GREEN:
        car.drive();
        break;
    case YELLOW:
        car.drive();
        break;
    case RED:
        car.stop();
        break;
}
```

Seems kinda wasteful since GREEN and YELLOW both do the same thing. Java lets us consolidate so that multiple conditions take the same action:

```
switch(trafficLight.state) {
    case GREEN:
    case YELLOW:
        // Now both GREEN and YELLOW will use this code
        car.drive();
        break;
    case RED:
        car.stop();
        break;
}
```

Less code, same effect. That's all. That's the *simple* case mind you, there are other ways to use this that are less obvious and more prone to abuse.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `car.floorIt()` for `case YELLOW` ?

Answer (score 0):

When parsing through a switch-case statement, each case is simply a label.  If anything matches a case then it will just go through until it either finds a break or the end of the statement (a `}`).

It is similar to the Java opcode (assembly code essentially).  You use labels to jump to.  Besides that, they don't really serve a purpose in the code.