# Strange semantics of switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I met this variations of switch statement, and I wondering to know in witch cases it can be used?

Strangeness is because it doesn't have cases before default value, only after. And doesn't have `break` statement. But works fine.

Here is code:

```
public static Item newItem() {
    switch (rand.nextInt(3)) {
    default:
    case 0:
        return new Scissors();
    case 1:
        return new Paper();
    case 2:
        return new Rock();
    }
}
```

How does it really can be execute at this strange style. I tried to make easy debugging all works fine it return accuracy one explicit instance.

Question: why does we need write:

```
default:
case 0:
```

instead typical usage:

```
case 0:
default:
```

Compiler didn't let to change or comment `default` statement.

Any suggestions?

***PS*** please, don't write silly explanation how does `switch` works. it's clear. write only about this explicit example.

***BTW*** I met this peace of code at [Thinking in Java by Bruce Eckel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131872486).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we need break after case statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710300/why-do-we-need-break-after-case-statements)

Comment: `return` causes the switch to exit the method thus none of the following options are ever executed.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth we have return statements thus we don't need any `break` statements there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `default` branch just means "the branch for all the options not explicitly specified. It's a convention to put it at the end of the `switch-case` statement, but is not required.

`break` is also not required - if a branch of the `switch-case` does not end with `break`, it will just continue on executing the code in the next branch - this is called *fallthrough*. However, here you do not need it because each branch just `return`s, so the function's execution does not continue.

Answer (score 1):

`Return` causes the exit. There's no need to add a `break` statement.

Comment: but why after default statement.

Comment: No matter where you put the `default` statement. Although it is common to put it at the end of the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` is optional. If a case matches and no `break` is encountered, the following `case` is executed without being tested. That's why

```
case 0:
default:
  // Some code here
```

works as you expect it to.

The `default` case is special. It is executed if no other `case` matches. It does not matter where you put it (at the beginning, in the middle or (as is custom) at the end).

In your code, if `case 0:` matches, `case 1:` is not executed only because the function never gets that far: a `new Scissors()` is returned instead.

Answer (score 0):

The method should return a value, as it declared by the method, so it should have a `return` statement. If you comment `default` the method might not return the value. It doesn't matter where you put `default` but you should do it to satisfy return condition.

Answer (score -2):

The code could be modified for improved readability and a standard look:

```
switch(...)
{
  case 0:
    ...
  case 1:
    ...
  case 2:
    ...
  default:
    // Not reachable
    throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected value");
}
```

Default label is necessary since the compiler cannot guess that only 0, 1 and 2 are possible.