# How do I delete an item through the menu?

Tags: java, android

Below is the code for my submenu buttons and I'm trying to make it delete the note and return to the main list view. The delete option is called "Red" for now.

I copied my delete code from my main activity thinking it would work, but it does not. I'm very new to android coding, so help would be appreciated.

This is how I delete in my Main Activity.java

```
    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    currentNoteId = (int)info.id;
    menu.add(0, MENU_DELETE_ID, 0, "Delete");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == MENU_DELETE_ID) {
        Noteitem note = notesList.get(currentNoteId);
        datasource.remove(note);
        refreshDisplay();

    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Here is my code for my NoteEditorActivity.java 
Again I'm trying to delete, but I can't seem to figure out how to delete the note from the submenu.

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_exit:
        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.noteText);
        if (et.length() > 0) {
            saveAndFinish();
        } 
            else 
        {
        finish();
            }

    case R.id.menu_red:
        currentNoteId = (int) MENU_DELETE_ID;  
        datasource.remove(note);
        return true;  


        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: so , what's the problem ?

Comment: @mohammed_momn I'm trying to delete an item, but the code does not work.

Comment: i think you missing the break in switch statement

Comment: @mohammed_momn Could you provide me an example? I'm not really sure what that is.

Comment: does `R.id.menu_red` really equal to `MENU_DELETE_ID`? if so, it's redundant to compare it again and if not, then it's the error

Comment: @simekadam I realize that that part of the code was irrelevant. At least I think so. I simply need to remove/delete the note.

Comment: Could you post code for the datasource.remove() method?

Comment: What means "doesn't work"? In a sense, almost any piece of software doesn't work.

Comment: @simekadam I just updated my code with everything that I have.

Comment: Was this from a sample app or coded from scratch?  Could you link to the source, that might help.

Comment: @MichaelHerbig I updated my code and yes I made it from scratch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need break after case statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710300/why-do-we-need-break-after-case-statements)

Answer (score 0):

Put break statements in your switch case

```
switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case R.id.action_exit:
            EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.noteText);
            if (et.length() > 0){
                saveAndFinish();
            }else{
                finish();
            }
        //you are missing this!!!
        break;

        case R.id.menu_red:
            datasource.remove(note);
            finish();   
        break;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        break;
    }
```

Try reading this here also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 0):

its just weird..you aren't calling `notesList.add()` method anywhere in your code, so I just think it's empty at all..
you are certainly missing the break statement there, but I guess it is not the issue why your note is not deleted after clicking in the menu item. You are saving your note in the "previous" (in terms of backstack) activity? if so, you might try to just alter the return code for the `setActivityResult()`  call (or add some extras to the intent) and then check for it in your `onActivityResult()` callback..
because right now everytime you close the activity via back key, the notes is saved (the `saveAndFinish()` method gets called);
please describe better where you actually do save notes (to DB or so) and where you wanna delete them..I could then provide you with some code snippet probably.

Comment: Hello @simekadam I have updated the code to hopefully reveal a bit more information on how I delete from the main activity vs noteeditor