# Switch executes all case statements

Tags: java, for-loop, case

Can someone explain me why my loop is going from 0 to 7? I need to get only in the first 3 cases, but the program is going through all.. The code is in the show() method.

```
for(brojac=0; brojac<3; brojac++){

    switch(brojac){
    case 1:
        figura1.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
        stage.addActor(figura1);
        System.out.println("1");
    case 2:
        figura2.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
        stage.addActor(figura2);
        System.out.println("2");
    case 3:
        figura3.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
        stage.addActor(figura3);
        System.out.println("3");
    case 4:
        figura4.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
        stage.addActor(figura4);
        System.out.println("4");
    case 5:
        figura5.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
        stage.addActor(figura5);
        System.out.println("5");
    case 6:
        figura6.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
        stage.addActor(figura6);
        System.out.println("6");
    case 7:
        figura7.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
        stage.addActor(figura7);
        System.out.println("7");

    }
}
```

Comment: did you forget to add the "break;" statement after each case block?

Comment: Yes, go back to your textbook and look at the description of a `switch` statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need break after case statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710300/why-do-we-need-break-after-case-statements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the break is missing. After every case you need the break keyword. For a detailed explanation see [switch statement java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

e.g.

```
for(brojac=0; brojac<3; brojac++){

switch(brojac){
case 1:
    figura1.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
    stage.addActor(figura1);
    System.out.println("1");
    break; /// Break here

case 2:
    figura2.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
    stage.addActor(figura2);
    System.out.println("2");
    break; /// Break here
case 3:
    figura3.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
    stage.addActor(figura3);
    System.out.println("3");
    break; /// Break here
case 4:
    figura4.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
    stage.addActor(figura4);
    System.out.println("4");
    break; /// Break here
case 5:
    figura5.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
    stage.addActor(figura5);
    System.out.println("5");
    break; /// Break here
case 6:
    figura6.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
    stage.addActor(figura6);
    System.out.println("6");
    break; /// Break here
case 7:
    figura7.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
    stage.addActor(figura7);
    System.out.println("7");
    break; /// Break here
}
}
```

Otherwise the other cases will be executed if one of the above cases gets evaluated to true.

Answer (score 1):

That's how [Java's `switch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statements work.

They "fall through" the cases once one of them matches. You need to add `break;` after all your cases.

```
for(brojac=0; brojac<3; brojac++){

    switch(brojac){
    case 1:
        figura1.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
        stage.addActor(figura1);
        System.out.println("1");
        break;
    case 2:
        figura2.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
        stage.addActor(figura2);
        System.out.println("2");
        break;
    case 3:
        figura3.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
        stage.addActor(figura3);
        System.out.println("3");
        break;
    case 4:
        figura4.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
        stage.addActor(figura4);
        System.out.println("4");
        break;
    case 5:
        figura5.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
        stage.addActor(figura5);
        System.out.println("5");
        break;
    case 6:
        figura6.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
        stage.addActor(figura6);
        System.out.println("6");
        break;
    case 7:
        figura7.setPosition(pomx[random], pomy[random]);
        stage.addActor(figura7);
        System.out.println("7");
        break;

    }
}
```