# How to stop switch statement if it is executing all other case in C?

Tags: c, switch-statement, case

**Problem**

This program giving me wrong result for odd numbers because second case statement also executing every time. Please tell me why this happening.

**Program**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int num,rem,te=0,to=0,e=0,o=0;
    float ae,ao;

    while (1) {

    printf("\nEnter Number : ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if (num==0) break;
    rem=num%2;
    switch (rem) {

        case 0 :
            te+=num;
            e++;

        case 1 :
            to+=num;
            o++;

    }
}   
printf("\nTotal of even numbers : %d",te);
printf("\nTotal of odd numbers : %d",to);
printf("\nTotal of number of even numbers : %d",e);
printf("\nTotal of number of odd numbers : %d",o);
printf("\nAverage of even no. : %f",ae=te/e);
printf("\nAverage of odd no. : %f",ao=to/o);        

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

> **output:**
>
> Enter Number : 1
>
> Enter Number : 2
>
> Enter Number : 3
>
> Enter Number : 4
>
> Enter Number : 5
>
> Enter Number : 6
>
> Enter Number : 0
>
> Total of even numbers : 12
>
> Total of odd numbers : 21
>
> Total of number of even numbers : 3
>
> Total of number of odd numbers : 6
>
> Average of even no. : 4.000000
>
> Average of odd no. : 3.000000

Comment: add a `break;` That'll help

Comment: `te/e` will result in an `int`, you have lost the digits after the decimal already. No point in assigning it to a `float` if accuracy is your goal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch executes all case statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012061/switch-executes-all-case-statements)

Comment: Please upvote this as this is no longer an invalid question.Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `switch` in C has a *follow-through* feature meaning that program control runs into the cases below the one you enter. You can cancel that effect by using a `break` statement:

```
switch (rem){
case 0:
    te+=num;
    e++;
    break;
case 1:
    to+=num;
    o++;
}
```

In your case though you could use the considerably simpler

```
if (num % 2){
    to += num;
    ++o;
} else {
    te += num;
    ++e;
}
```

And also beware that your averages will be calculated in *integer arithmetic*. Use `1f * te / e` instead, taking care to check that `e` is not zero.

Answer (score 2):

Add `break;` at the end of each case.

```
switch (rem) {

    case 0 :
        te+=num;
        e++;
        break;

    case 1 :
        to+=num;
        o++;
        break;
}
```