# Weird error with an ArrayList in for-loop

Tags: java, arraylist, switch-statement

I have a  very weird problem, the problem only presents itself in case 3 & 4.

```
                for(Sector sector : sectoren)
    {
        switch(sector.getCode())
        {
            case 1:
                for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<3; j++)
                    {
                        Gebiedskaart gbk = gebiedskaarten.get(r.nextInt(gebiedskaarten.size()));
                        vakken[i][j].setGbk(gbk);
                        gebiedskaarten.remove(gbk);
                    }
                vakken[2][2].setGbk(null);
                }
            case 2:
                for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=4;j<7; j++)
                    {
                        Gebiedskaart gbk = gebiedskaarten.get(r.nextInt(gebiedskaarten.size()));
                        vakken[i][j].setGbk(gbk);
                        gebiedskaarten.remove(gbk);
                    }
                }
                vakken[2][4].setGbk(null);
            case 3:
                for(int i=4; i<7; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<3; j++)
                    {
                        System.out.println(gebiedskaarten.size());
                        Gebiedskaart gbk = gebiedskaarten.get(r.nextInt(gebiedskaarten.size()));
                        vakken[i][j].setGbk(gbk);
                        gebiedskaarten.remove(gbk);
                    }
                }
                vakken[4][2].setGbk(null);
           case 4:
                for(int i = 4; i<7; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=4;j<7; j++)
                    {
                        Gebiedskaart gbk = gebiedskaarten.get(r.nextInt(gebiedskaarten.size()));
                        vakken[i][j].setGbk(gbk);
                        //gebiedskaarten.remove(gbk); doet iets raar? moeten we nog naar kijken, hij blijft gewoon verwijderen tot de lijst leeg is
                    }
                }
                vakken[4][4].setGbk(null);
        }
    }
```

in the code you can see that I assign a value to an array, and then i remove that value from the ArrayList. You can see I have put the System.out.println there, to see what it does, and this is the output:

```
34
33
32
31
30
29
28
27
26
16
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

And then the error obviously:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:300)
    at domein.Spelbord.wijsGebiedskaartenToe(Spelbord.java:123)
    at domein.Spelbord.<init>(Spelbord.java:19)
    at domein.Spel.setWereldkaart(Spel.java:18)
    at domein.DomeinController.maakWereldkaart(DomeinController.java:39)
    at ui.Uc1.maakWereldkaart(Uc1.java:42)
    at ui.ConsoleApplicatie.behandelUc1(ConsoleApplicatie.java:67)
    at ui.ConsoleApplicatie.startSpel(ConsoleApplicatie.java:29)
    at StartUp.main(StartUp.java:12)
Java Result: 1
```

I don't have a clue of whats going on, maybe you guys have?

Comment: Your loop seems to run only 9 (3 * 3) times, how can it print out so much?

Comment: The inner part of your loop runs 9 times, which removes 9 elements (35 -> 26). So the rest of the output (from 16 on) is the result of some other code. For better help sooner, try to provide a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your last printout of `gebiedskaarten.size()` is `0`, which, when passed to `r.nextInt()`, is going to be passing a non-positive number (`0`) to `Random#nextInt`, hence the error that occurs in `java.util.Random.nextInt` (look at your stack trace).

Comment: This is still not compilable code, to really 100% assess your problem we need more code... (*but definately not all your code!*) However I also believe that with the current answers on `Random#nextInt` you have enough material to start to get it working.

Comment: Problem was I forgot the break statements

Answer (score 4):

It is because you do:

```
 r.nextInt(gebiedskaarten.size());
```

when `gebiedskaarten.size() == 0`

==> you try get a random number from 0 to 0 ==> Exception

**Update:** it also looks like you forgot the `break;` statements in your switch-case! I guess you want to be your code logic to be like that:

```
 switch(sector.getCode()) {
 case 1: /*do something*/ break;
 case 2: /*do something else */ break;
 //...
 default: //do some default action
 }
```

see also related question: [Why do we need break after case statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710300/why-do-we-need-break-after-case-statements)

Comment: Yes but it isnt supposed to be 0

Comment: @stijn26 ahh! Did you forget the `break;` statements in your switch-case?

Comment: This was the error, omg I can't believe i forgot the break statements, everything runs fine now.

Now time for sleep, I can't think clearly!

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `Random.nextInt()` with a value of 0, which is not supported.

As you see from the output of `System.out`, the array finally has a size of 0, and you are passing the array's size to `nextInt()`.

See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)

Comment: Yes but it isnt supposed to be 0

Comment: Thats a different issue then - I see that you updated your code, but I think that it now contains too much irrelevant code - can you shrink it down further so that it contains the minimum code required to reproduce the issue (see http://sscce.org for some good reading)? At the end, the problem is most certainly that you call `remove` too often, so that you end up with a size of 0 - note the remark from @donfuxx about the missing `break`s!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why your loop runs so many times, while only 9 (3 * 3) times is expected, but assuming that the code you posted starts when `gebiedskaarten.size() == 9`, it does the follow for 9 iterations:

- `System.out.println(gebiedskaarten.size())`

  - Prints the current size.
- `Gebiedskaart gbk = gebiedskaarten.get(r.nextInt(gebiedskaarten.size()))`

  - First executes `r.nextInt(...)` with `gebiedskaarten.size()`, obtaining a new random value.
  - Then calls `gebiedskaarten.get(...)` with that random number and assigns it to `gbk`.
- `vakken[i][j].setGbk(gbk);`

  - Calls `setGbk(gbk)` on the `i, j` entry of `vakken`.
- `gebiedskaarten.remove(gbk);`

  - Removes `gbk` from the `gebiedskaarten` collection, reducing the size by one.

Where it goes wrong, is that a certain point, `gebiedskaarten.size()` becomes `0`, and you try to obtain a new random via `r.nextInt(...)` on `0`, which is not possible, as it needs to be strictly positive.
Note however that calling `gebiedskaarten.get(0)` is valid, so you have an one-off error.

I also strongly suggest you to move from Dutch naming conventions to English naming conventions, as it will help you a lot in either your career future and in posting questions online.

Also, for completeness' sake, as @donfuxx has pointed out, your `switch` statements are not conform standards, which lead to errors in 99% of the time, it should be such:

```
switch (variable) {
    case 1:
        //do interesting things
        break;
    case 2:
        //do interesting things
        break;
    case 3:
        //do interesting things
        break;
    default:
        //either allowable base case, or may-not-happen error case
        break;
```

As you see I have added a `break` at the end of every `case`, this is neccessary to prevent it from falling through the statements. If there is no `break` at the end of `case 1`, then `case 2` will **also** get executed.

Comment: Yes I agree with that you should only use English names in your code