# Why is Break needed when using Switch?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I've read quite a few answers on SO but can't seem to find a definitive answer as to why if break is omitted in this instance the case "C" will always be evaluated as true and the new array filled will only "G"'s.  I clearly understand that break would be best used here as I am only looking to evaluate a specific match but not so as to why the last case is always true if break is indeed omitted.

```
 var dna = "ATTGC";
 var outArr = [];
 dna.split("").forEach(function(e,i){
    switch(e) {
        case "G": outArr[i] = "C"; break;
        case "T": outArr[i] = "A"; break;
        case "A": outArr[i] = "T"; break;
        case "C": outArr[i] = "G"; break;
    }
    console.log(outArr);
  })
```

Comment: The `switch...case` statement is designed such that if you omit the `break` statement, the evaluation of the condition "falls through" down the various cases. So, what you are seeing when you omit `break` is the condition matching each and every case until the last one.

Comment: It's not that the last case is true, rather that each case is an entry point after which all statements will be executed until the end of the `switch` block.

Comment: Additional to what jeyoung has commented. The `break;` is there for a good reason, if you want to do same stuff for different cases you can do it and break stops it from happening.

Comment: I think the reason you haven't found much on SO about `switch...case` is because it's absolute entry level programming concept that is covered alongside loops and other beginner level materials. It's furthermore cross-language concept since  the syntax of `switch` is pretty much exactly the same accross many languages. As such, this question is an exact duplicate of [this Java question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710300/why-do-we-need-break-after-case-statements) - in fact, the question and accepted answer are 100% compatible to JS since they don't use specific Java keywords.

Answer (score 10):

From MDN

> If a match is found, the program executes the associated statements. If multiple cases match the provided value, the first case that matches is selected, even if the cases are not equal to each other.
>
> The optional break statement associated with each case label ensures that the program breaks out of switch once the matched statement is executed and continues execution at the statement following switch. If break is omitted, the program continues execution at the next statement in the switch statement.

So the basic history about ***Switch*** is it originated from C and is an abstraction of [branch table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table) and a branch table also has an implicit fall-through and requires an additional jump instruction to avoid it.
Also all other languages inherited switch as default C switch semantics mostly choosing to keep the C semantics per default.
So in your switch if break is omitted from all cases, if the match is found program continues execution for next statement. It doesn't exit from switch after the match is found instead it evaluates all other case below the matched case, **as *parser thinks cases are combined, since there is no break in between them***.
I have modified your code a bit for clear explanation of this behavior.In case **A** break is omitted.

```
var dna = "ATTGC";
var outArr = [];
dna.split("").forEach(function(e,i){
switch(e) {
    case "G": outArr[i] = "C"; break;
    case "T": outArr[i] = "A"; break;
    case "A": outArr[i] = "T";
    case "C": outArr[i] = "G"; break;
}
console.log(outArr);
})
```

So your Output will be like

```
["G"]
["G", "A"]
["G", "A", "A"]
["G", "A", "A", "C"]
["G", "A", "A", "C", "G"]
```

In first iteration match will be for case **A**.

```
outArr={'T'}
```

Again Since there is no *break* statement, it will consider Case **C** as same block and continues execution there. Now

```
outArr={'G'}
```

Similalrly in second iteration it matches for case **T** but there is a *break* statement so controls jumps out of the switch and outarr will now be

```
outArr={'G','A'}
```

Similarly for other iterations you will get the whole output as posted above.

> Updated Bin [here](https://jsbin.com/dificosura/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Are there useful cases where you want to omit the `break`? It looks like omitted `break`s 
can cause only buggy behavior, so why that keyword is optional?

Comment: Yup, there are cases where you might want to omit `break`. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#methods_for_multi-criteria_case

Answer (score 3):

`switch` and `if/else` are somewhat interchangeable, EXCEPT for exactly what `break` allows for in a switch. In and `if/elseif/elseif/..../else` chain, only **ONE** of the blocks will ever execute, e.g.

```
x = 7;
if (x == 5) {
    ... no match, not executed at all
} else if (x == 7) {
   .... match made, this is executed
} else if (x == 7) {
   ... this will not execute, because the other block already did
} else {
   ... this also never executes, because a match was made earlier
}
```

In comparison, with a `switch`, once a match is made, no further comparison tests are done, and ALL code following will be executed, until the switch block closes (`}`), or a `break` is encountered:

```
x = 7;
switch(x) {
    case 5:   ... nothing matched, not executed; break;
    case 7: do_something();
    case 8: other_stuff();
    case 9: foo(); break;
    case 7: ... will not execute, because matching stopped above.
    default: stuff();
}
```

Note the lack of a `break` on the `case 7` line. That means execution continues, and ignores all further `case` lines. that means `do_something()` executes, then `other_stuff()` executes, and `foo()` executes. Finally a `break` is encountered, which terminates this now long-running `case`, and the execution then proceeds on with whatever comes AFTER the `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

When a case matches, if you don't break, it will continue onto the next case regardless of whether it matches the condition. So they will all hit the last case and the output will be overridden with "G"