# Why does switch-case strict equality check seems to fail in this example?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case

If the result of this code illustrates that the switch-case implies strict equality checking..

```
//code 1

switch(0)
{
case false: alert('NOT strict');
break;
case 0: alert('strict');    // shows up as expected
}
```

..then why does the result of the second one seem to tell the opposite?.. Did any type conversion occur or something?

```
// code 2

switch(0)
{
case 0: alert('may or may not be strict');    // I just added this case.. does it have an effect.. why?
case false: alert('NOT strict');    // this shows up!..
break;
case 0: alert('strict');    // ..instead of this!
}
```

note 1: My question here is not whether strict equality checking occurs or not.. I already looked up that question's answer here.  My question is.. why that contradiction between the two results? 
 Shouldn't code 2 give us 'strict' instead of 'NOT strict'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Break needed when using Switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757797/why-is-break-needed-when-using-switch)

Comment: Although they are related.. this question is not a a duplicate of that one.. simply because.. I had no idea that the issue has to do with leaving the break statement.. and that's why I haven't even mentioned it.. but.. once I learned that the issue actually has to do with leaving the break statement.. the question you mentioned is the next logical one.. and that's why they are related.. not duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

In your second version you left out `break` at the end of the first `case 0:`. So it continues with the next case without performing its test. Then the `break` statement prevents it from executing the second `case 0:`.

Comment: "without performing its test".. why?!

Comment: Because that's the way `switch/case` works. It looks for the first `case` that matches the value, then starts executing code from there until it gets to `break`.

Comment: This allows you to write something like `switch($answer) { case 'y': case 'yes': ...; break; case 'n': case 'no': ...; break }`

Answer (score 0):

You have no break statement, so the [execution falls-through](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#What_happens_if_I_forgot_a_break). It's no different than this:

```js
switch(0)
{
case 0:
  alert('case 0');
  // no break statement, so the next case runs if this one did
case 'bologna':
  alert('case bologna');
}
```