# Switch Function Outputting Out of Order And Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm trying to iterate through an array and have multiple cases for what the object in the array could be...

```
   for (var i = 0; i < firstWords.length; i++) 
    {
        var keyword = firstWords[i];
        var orderNumber = 0;
        var type = [];
        switch(keyword) {
            case 'const':
                console.log("Constant Defined");
            case 'function': 
                console.log('Function Defined');
            default: 
                console.log('Misc');
        }
    }
```

It does go through the array and log a response based on what the object is, but the order in which it logs it is weird.
I input this as a test:

```
const
const
const
function
misc
```

And it logs this:

```
Constant Defined
Function Defined
Misc
Constant Defined
Function Defined
Misc
Constant Defined
Function Defined
Misc
Function Defined
(2)Misc
```

What I want it to do is log each one in order. So in this case, it should say "Constant defined" 3 times first, and then "Function defined" and "Misc"
How do I get it to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: You need `break;` statements in the `case`s in your `switch`.  Like: `case 'const': console.log("Constant Defined"); break;`.

Comment: You're missing 'break` expressions, so the switch is continuing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757797/why-is-break-needed-when-using-switch