# I'm confused by execution of switch statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a little confused with the below code, it is printing step 3 to the console

```
let switch; 
switch('abc'){
  case('abc'): 
    switch = 'step 1';
  case('def'): 
    switch = 'step 2';
  default: 
    switch = 'step 3';
}
console.log(switch);
```

Comment: What specifically are you confused about?

Comment: you didn't use break;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Break needed when using Switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757797/why-is-break-needed-when-using-switch)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're missing the `break` statement that prevents it from executing subsequent code

```
let switch; 
switch('abc'){
  case('abc'): 
    switch = 'step 1';
    break;
  case('def'): 
    switch = 'step 2';
    break;
  default: 
    switch = 'step 3';
}
console.log(switch);
```

putting the console log into the swi9tch, hopefully that illustrates the point

```js
switch ("abc") {
  case "abc":
    console.log("step 1 - no break");
  case "def":
    console.log("step 2 - no break");
  default:
    console.log("step 3 - no break");
}

switch ("abc") {
  case "abc":
    console.log("step 1");
    break;
  case "def":
    console.log("step 2");
    break;
  default:
    console.log("step 3");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding break; statement, this code will still be ineffectual. You need to also add something like user input to make switch determine which case it will run.