# Why do these two switch statements give different outputs to console?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

These two switch statements are the same, other than the use of console.log.
When outputting the result to the chrome console I get two different results.
The first one outputs:

this is the one

while the second outputs:

1

this is the one

Why is that?

```js
const q = 1;
switch (q) {

    case '1':
        answer = "one";

    case 1:
       answer = 1;

    case 2:
       answer = "this is the one";
        break;

    default:
        answer = "not working";

}
console.log(answer);

const q1 = 1;
switch (q1) {

    case '1':
        console.log("one");

    case 1:
       console.log(1);

    case 2:
        console.log("this is the one");
        break;

    default:
        console.log ("not working");
}
```

Comment: You need to use `break` for every case.

Comment: READ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#breaking_and_fall-through

Comment: because a switch is not "if ... else if ... else if ... else ...", it's "turn this switch on once a case matches, _and stay on_ until the end of the switch block". If you only need it to trigger a single thing, for a low number of cases consider not using a switch at all, or add `break` everywhere.

Comment: Have you tried stepping line by line through the code using your debugger? It would show you which lines are evaluated. You'd be surprised.

Answer (score 1):

I put a star(*) on the lines that executed.
The switches need breaks, or else one hit can execute multiple sections.

```
*const q = 1;
*switch (q) {

    case '1':
        answer = "one";

    case 1:
*       answer = 1;

    case 2:
*       answer = "this is the one";  //changed the value of answer
*        break;

    default:
        answer = "not working";

}
*console.log(answer); //the first line of output.

*const q1 = 1;
*switch (q1) {

    case '1':
        console.log("one");

    case 1:  //where the hit occurred.
*       console.log(1);  // the second line of output.

    case 2:
*        console.log("this is the one");  //the third line of output.
*        break;

    default:
        console.log ("not working");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A switch is not like a if/else if/ else. In an if structure it only runs the code in the block that follows it.

In a switch a case statement falls through to the next. If you do not want it to fall through you add a break.

```js
function countDown(start) { 
  console.log('called with: ', start);
  switch (start) {  
    case 3:
    case 'three':
          console.log(3);
    case 2:
    case 'two':
          console.log(2);
    case 1:
    case 'one':
      console.log(1);
  }
}

countDown(3); // 3 2 1
countDown('two');  // 2 1
```

Now when you add a break it will not fall through

```js
function countDown(start) { 
  console.log('called with: ', start);
  switch (start) {  
    case 3:
    case 'three':
          console.log(3);
          break;
    case 2:
    case 'two':
          console.log(2);
          break;
    case 1:
    case 'one':
      console.log(1);
      break;
  }
}

countDown(3); // 3
countDown('two');  // 2
```

Comment: specifically, it acts like an actual, physical switch. It turns on at some point _and then stays on_.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not using `break;` at the end of each `case` block. Use something like this:

```js
const q = 1;
switch (q) {

    case '1':
        answer = "one";
        break;

    case 1:
       answer = 1;
       break;

    case 2:
       answer = "this is the one";
        break;

    default:
        answer = "not working";

}
console.log(answer);

const q1 = 1;
switch (q1) {

    case '1':
        console.log("one");
        break;

    case 1:
       console.log(1);
       break;

    case 2:
        console.log("this is the one");
        break;

    default:
        console.log ("not working");
}
```

`break;` just means that stop the execution here and don't move to the block below, just like in your case

Answer (score 0):

If we execute each line of code or verify each line code, you can see, in first switch case is executed `case 1` and then`case 2`, which makes value = `this is the one` now the break is executed and we are out of switch case 1.

Now,`console.log(answer);` hits and prints `this is the one`

Next, q1 =1

```
case 1:
   console.log(1);

case 2:
    console.log("this is the one");
```

Both of the above statement executes since, case 1 is correct match for switch case number 2, but there is no `break` so case 2 is also executed.

Hence, you see this output.
You can also refer these links also: [Why is Break needed when using Switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757797/why-is-break-needed-when-using-switch)

https://javascript.info/switch

Answer (score 0):

You need to add break to skip the next switch case.

```
switch (month) {
case 1:
case 3:
case 5:
case 7:
case 8:
case 10:
case 12:
    conosle.log('case is 1 to 12');
    break;
case 13:
    console.log('case 13');
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

const q = 1;
switch (q) {

```
case '1':
    answer = "one";

case 1:
   answer = 1;

case 2:
   answer = "this is the one";
    break;

default:
    answer = "not working";
```

}
console.log(answer);

switch case default behaviour is that when a case will get true value then the following case statements will run without checking the condition . in this case case 1 is implemented as true so the next cases will not evaluate .

const q1 = 1;
switch (q1) {

```
case '1':
    console.log("one");

case 1:
   console.log(1);

case 2:
    console.log("this is the one");
    break;

default:
    console.log ("not working");
```

}

in your second code , case 1 will evaluated as true so the compiler will not evaluate your case 2 . it will directly go to the case 2 block and console that until compiler find a break s