# Rotating "Cells" around origin

Tags: java

So in this piece of code i'm writing I have these shapes defined by an ArrayList of Point objects, these points represent cells on a grid. Each shape has an x and a y, which is the centre of the shape, in an absolute coordinate system - bottom left corner would be 0, 0 etc. Each of the shapes should be able to rotate around the centre. I have defined these shapes in their "north facing" orientation using coordinates relative to their centre. How would I be able to retrieve a list of absolute coordinates for each cell given the parameters x and y for the centre of the shape for each of the four directions N, E, S, W.

```
ArrayList<Point> adjustedCells = new ArrayList<Point>();

for(Point point : cells) {
    Point adjustedPoint;
    switch (getOrientation()) {
    case NORTH:
        adjustedPoint = new Point(x + point.x, y + point.y);
        adjustedCells.add(adjustedPoint);
    case SOUTH:
        adjustedPoint = new Point(x - point.x, y - point.y);
        adjustedCells.add(adjustedPoint);
    case EAST:
        adjustedPoint = new Point(x - point.y, y + point.x);
        adjustedCells.add(adjustedPoint);
    case WEST:
        adjustedPoint = new Point(x + point.y, y - point.x);
        adjustedCells.add(adjustedPoint);
    }
}
```

This is what I tried based on other code I've found but it's clearly not giving the correct coordinates. This piece is just inside a method with the parameters x and y which are the centre x and y of the shape in absolute.

Comment: In your question, add the resulting coordinates you get from your code for a simple example shape, and add the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just see a couple of issues with your code, one related to geometry and the other to how the switch statement works in Java.

Firstly the switch statement. You need to `break` after each case to stop "falling through" to the following case. For more detail on this take a look at [Why do we need break after case statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710300/why-do-we-need-break-after-case-statements)

Secondly the geometry. This is almost correct, you just have the EAST and WEST cases swapped. Your relative cell locations are vectors. The coordinates of a (NORTH) vector (x,y) rotated 90 degrees clockwise (EAST) are (y, -x). For a counter clockwise rotation (WEST) they're (-y, x). Repeat either of these and you get the coordinates for a 180 degree rotation (SOUTH) (-x, -y), which you already had.

```
for(Point point : cells) {
  Point adjustedPoint;
  switch (getOrientation()) {
  case NORTH:
      adjustedPoint = new Point(x + point.x, y + point.y);
      adjustedCells.add(adjustedPoint);
      break;
  case SOUTH:
      adjustedPoint = new Point(x - point.x, y - point.y);
      adjustedCells.add(adjustedPoint);
      break;
  case EAST:
      adjustedPoint = new Point(x + point.y, y - point.x);
      adjustedCells.add(adjustedPoint);
      break;
  case WEST:
      adjustedPoint = new Point(x - point.y, y + point.x);
      adjustedCells.add(adjustedPoint);
      break;
  }     
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, I knew it was something simple like that. Could for the life of me see it though.