# React.js switch case always returns default case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am trying to use `<select>` tags to update information between components with the help of `useContext()`. The problem that I am facing is that the `default` case is always returned despite the `console.log` matching the set `case` values.

The renderer for the different selects.

```
const selectNames = [
     "Strength",
     "Dexterity",
     "Constitution",
     "Intelligence",
     "Wisdom",
     "Charisma"
]

const options = [
        {
            label: '16',
            value: '16'
        },
        {
            label: '14',
            value: '14-1'
        },
        {
            label: '14',
            value: '14-2'
        },
        {
            label: '12',
            value: '12-1'
        },
        {
            label: '12',
            value: '12-2'
        },
        {
            label: '10',
            value: '10'
        }
    ]

const selectRender = selectNames.map((name, index) => {
   return (
      <>
         <label for={name}>{name}:</label>
         <select name={name} key={index} onChange={handleChange} value={chosenOptions[name] || ''}
                 required={index === 0} id={name.toLowerCase()}>
              <option value=''/>
              {options.filter(({value}) => !isChosenByOther(value, name))
                   .map(({label, value}, oIndex) =>
                        <option value={value} key={oIndex}>{label}</option>)
               }
         </select>
     </>
   )
})
```

Here's the code for the event handler function containing the `switch` case.

The `setStrength()` and other like functions are the de-structured functions from the context component and I believe are referenced correctly. Additionally, if there is a problem with them I don't think it would matter for this specific issue as the code never calls them.

```
const handleChange = (ev) => {
        setChosenOptions({...chosenOptions, [ev.target.name]: ev.target.value});
        console.log(ev.target.name)
        switch (ev.target.name) {
            case "Strength":
                setStrength(ev.target.value)
            case "Dexterity":
                setDexterity(ev.target.value)
            case "Constitution":
                setConstitution(ev.target.value)
            case "Intelligence":
                setIntelligence(ev.target.value)
            case "Wisdom":
                setWisdom(ev.target.value)
            case "Charisma":
                setCharisma(ev.target.value)
            default:
                console.log("attribute wasn't successfully changed")
        }
    };
```

Whenever I select values within the react app it correctly references the specific `<select>` I change but always calls the `default` function.

The console logs:

```
Intelligence

attribute wasn't successfully changed

Charisma

attribute wasn't successfully changed

Wisdom

attribute wasn't successfully changed
```

Let me know if you need to see different sections of code and what not.

Comment: Your switch [falls through](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#breaking_and_fall-through) until it reaches the `default`. Use `break;` after each statement.

Comment: Logging and/or debuggers and/or JS docs resolve issues like these in seconds.

Comment: Thank you. All my experience using switch statements for the past year have returned things within a function instead of calling a function so it was just a poor oversight on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `break` after each code block in your switch case. Check here for more details [Why do we need break after case statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710300/why-do-we-need-break-after-case-statements)