# HashMap and case construct

Tags: java, enums, hashmap, switch-statement

For readability reasons I'm trying to avoid using Char based case constructs, using Java 6. I cannot switch to 7 jet...

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
        put("foo", "--foo");
                put("bar), "--bar");
        ... 
    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; // java problem
};
```

The serialVersionUID - as far as I know, maybe part of the problem. Currently I'm working with if constructs:

```
if (!map.containsValue(args[0])) {
    logger.error("Unknown parameter:  " + args[0]);
        ...
```

I handle ~ 30 parameters. In any case a growing number.

Is it even possible to define `switch` constructs with enums or HashMaps In Java 6?

Comment: Sorry, but to me is totally unclear what are you trying to achieve... Could you clarify?

Comment: case doesn't work with Strings in Java. I try to use case with a HashMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're handling over 30 parameters in the same way, then you need some kind of loop. For example:

```
for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++)
{
   String param = args[i];
   if (!map.containsValue(param))
      logger.error("Unknown parameter:  " + param);
   .. handle argument
}
```

It looks like you are parsing command line arguments. There are some good libraries available that offer flexible command line parsing, for example [args4j](https://args4j.dev.java.net/). With args4j, you create your data model, and let it map fields in the data to command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

[Using Strings in a switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java) will be available [in Java 7](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_for_further_consideration).

For moderate or complex parsing of command line arguments I strongly recommend using [Commons-CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/), it provides a great API to make this much easier for you to handle. An [example of it's usage](http://commons.apache.org/cli/usage.html):

```
// create Options object
Options options = new Options();

// add t option
options.addOption("t", false, "display current time");
...

CommandLineParser parser = new PosixParser();
CommandLine cmd = parser.parse( options, args);

if(cmd.hasOption("t")) {
    // print the date and time
}
else {
    // print the date
}
```