# String as switch statement

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switch Statement with Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java)

I am trying to use switch statement on String but it gives compilation error. If any one suggest me how to use String in switch-case statement , it will be helpful to me.

Comment: Strings can't be used in switch statements in Java.

Comment: @Walkerneo Not true since Java7. Which is also the proposed fix: Use the newest version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way if you really really want to use switch statements.
Create an enum class which includes the switch statement cases

```
public enum MustUseSwitch{
    value1,
    value2,
    value3;
}
```

and then use the enum to switch to statements.

```
switch(MustUseSwitch.valueOf(stringVariable)){
    case value1:
        System.out.println("Value1!");
        break;
    case value2:
        System.out.println("Value2!");
        break;
    case value3:
        System.out.println("Value3!");
       break;
}
```

Comment: Well that's obviously the same as using a hashmap from String->integer - although a neat trick.

Answer (score 4):

As already said, you can't. For technical details you can refer to the specification about [compiling switches](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Compiling.doc.html#14942). With Java SE 7, this functionality has been implemented. See [this page](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/08/string-switch-case-jdk7-example.html) for an example using switch on `String` with JDK 7.

Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java) could be helpful too.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  Use if/else if/else if/else.  Unless you are on Java7.  This answer on this duplicate question can explain it far better than I can: https://stackoverflow.com/a/338230/3333

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use strings directly, but you can make an array of key strings, quickly search it, and switch on the index, like this:

```
String[] sortedKeys = new String[] {"alpha", "bravo", "delta", "zebra"};
int keyIndex = Arrays.binarySearch(sortedKeys, switchKey);
switch(keyIndex) {
    case 0: // alpha
        break;
    case 1: // bravo
        break;
    case 2: // delta
        break;
    case 3: // zebra
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `String` in a `switch` statement but you can use the `Enum` type. Using an `Enum` is much better than using a `String` or even a `public static final int MY_CONSTANT`.

You'll find a really good tutorial here: [Java Enum type tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)