# Switch statement within Do-While loop doesn't exit

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner, do-loops

The code doesn't exit after I type "stop" - for some reason. Why?
Step-by-step debugging shows that after I enter "stop" it's value consists of exactly 's','t','o','p' without any line breaks, etc. - however, the code still goesn't exit. Could anyone tell why, please?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // asking username
    System.out.print("Username: ");
    String username = input.nextLine();

    String inpText;
    do {
        System.out.print(username + "$: ");
        inpText = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\n");
        // analyzing
        switch (inpText) {
        case "start":
            System.out.println("> Machine started!");
            break;
        case "stop":
            System.out.println("> Stopped!");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("> Command not recognized");
        }
    } while (inpText != "stop");

    System.out.println("Bye!..");
}
}
```

Comment: read this: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) and then fix your `while` condition.

Comment: Thanks @jlordo. Couldn't imagine the reason was in the comparison itself; and the linked question covers everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To [compare Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) use `.equals()` and not `==`, unless you really know what you are doing.

> ```
> inpText != "stop" //Not recommended
> !"stop".equals(inpText) //recommended
> ```

- You cannot use a [String in a switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240538/use-string-in-switch-case-in-java) unless you are using jdk 1.7+.

> Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7.
>   Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted

Comment: Thanks @rocketboy. JDK is 7u17, and looks like it was a matter of correct comparison. However, acc. to specification of the `equals()` shouldn't `!inpText.equals("stop")` be more correct?

Comment: String equals is symmetric, so `a.equals(b)` is same as `b.equals(a)`. That said, if `inpText = null`, `inpText.equals("stop")` can throw a NPE but it won't be thrown for `"stop".equals(inpText)`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing pointers not strings with this piece of code:

```
while (inpText != "stop");
```

Should be something like this:

```
while (!"stop".equals(inpText));
```

Comment: Thanks Tristan. However, according to the function' specification shouldn't !inpText.equals("stop") be more correct?

Comment: evictorov: by writing it as !"stop".equals(inpText) you easily avoid any possible nullpointers. Its just a little trick I use quite often.

Answer (score 0):

change **while (inpText != "stop");** to **while (!(inpText.equals("stop")));**

Answer (score 0):

If your JDK is 1.6 or lower you can't switch() on a String

P.S.
switching on a String is probably not the best solution Yeah in java 1.6 you can only switch int, boolean, double, long, and float I believe.

Comment: Thanks Mohsin. Mine is 7u17.