# Using switch() with Scanner in Java error when running with Pico Compiler- Ipad

Tags: java, eclipse, ipad

I am running the following code on Eclipse with no errors. When I am trying to do the same with Pico compiler app on my Ipad I get 4 types of errors. The print screen are attached. Any idea why cannot running in the same way?

The code:

"''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class switchClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a command: ");
    String text = scanner.nextLine();
    scanner.close();
    switch(text) {
    case "start":
        System.out.println("Machine started");
        break;

    case "stop":
        System.out.println("Machine stopped");
        break;  

    default:
        System.out.println("Command not recognized!");
    }

    }

}
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Pico Compiler for Ipad running the code :

[image]

Pico Compiler errors :

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, switching `String`s was introduces with Java 7. Maybe your version of the Pico Compiler does not (fully) support Java 7?

Answer (score 1):

The Error says that you can't use a `String` in the `case`.

Using `String` in `switch` was introduced in **Java-7** and therefore, I suspect *Pico Compiler* uses **Java-6** or below.

*Fix*: [Use string in switch case in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240538/use-string-in-switch-case-in-java)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Most probably that's the cause. As I am currently learning Java and mostly is easy to have my tablet instead of the laptop with me all the time, can you recommend an online compiler which can support current java version?