# How to compare input values from user with values in array

Tags: java, android, arrays, switch-statement

I want to use existing array element as switch case rather giving constant string value to switch case

I have values in resource string array that I used to display, and user has to select from these display values, now I want to compare the input value that I saved in shared preference and the values that I have in array resource, I wrote something like this but it didn't work

```
private static String activity;
private static int result;
activity = SharedPrefUtils.getActivityLevel(context);

String[] activities 
= context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.activity);

switch (activity){
      //something like getting values from array
        case activities[0]:
            result = 0;
            break;
        case activities[1]:
            result = 200;
            break;
        case activities[2]:
            result = 300;
            break;
    }

    return result;
```

Comment: why  `static` ? remove this, it doesn´t give you any advantage...

Comment: Starting with JDK7 you can do [something like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240538/use-string-in-switch-case-in-java) and it will just translate it to an if/elseif block with String.equals(). What version are you using?

Comment: Your question is unclear - can you give an example of input and output for that method?

Comment: In my case i dnt want to give constant string to switch case, I want to utilize existing array that stores that string values that i want to use as switch case

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating through an `array`, you can convert it into a `List` and use `indexOf` to get the element index, e.g.:

```
String[] activities = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.activity);
List<String> activitiesList = Arrays.asList(activities);
int index = activitiesList.indexOf(activity);
```

This is what the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) says:

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in
>   this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More
>   formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null
>   : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.

So, you can base your logic on `index` value.

Another approach would be to use a `Map<Integer, String>` and pass the `Integer` key to the method based on whichever value is selected by a user.

Comment: In my case i dnt want to give constant string to switch case, I want to utilize existing array that stores that string values that i want to use as switch case

Comment: You can't write a switch with dynamic number of cases as in this example, number of cases will depend on number of elements. So, you should use either `indexOf` call or `for` loop.

Comment: if I'm doing case activities[0] : I'm getting constant expression required error, although activities[0] returns String

Comment: Its only allowing "somevalue" as case:

Comment: Ah yes, you can't use any variable in `switch` case unless it's final. So, it has to be a `String` literal. We can't use `switch` case I am afraid.

Comment: Is that limitation? It shoild be dynamic like we can use value from array dynamically in switch case

Comment: Have a look at switch case's documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure your "activity" String and the items of "activities" array are returning you some values. Try to print the values to check that. If all of them are returning you values then you can compare String in this way:

```
if (activity.equalsIgnoreCase(activities[0]){
   Log.e("Matched" , "Yeah, it matched");
}
```

You can match your all String values one by one in this way.

Comment: Yes, but I want to have dynamic selection through switch block, like i dont have to give case as "String" and could utilize array that storing that values

Comment: In my case i dnt want to give constant string to switch case, I want to utilize existing array that stores that string values that i want to use as switch case

Comment: Then run a loop on your activities array and compare each value of activities array with the value of activity string through equalsIgnoreCase method.