# Convert to a switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

How do I convert this to a switch statement? I have tried this a few times. I am not sure what I am missing.

```
double totalPrice = 0.0;
if (venue.equals("Rod Laver")) {
    totalPrice = 225.25 * numOfTickets;
} else if (venue.equals("Margaret Court")) {
    totalPrice = 177.75 * numOfTickets;
} else if (venue.equals("John Cain")) {
    totalPrice = 145.50 * numOfTickets;
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid venue entered");
     // Exit program if venue is invalid
}

// Display the total price to the user
System.out.printf("\nHave a wonderful day at the %s venue.\n\n", venue);
System.out.printf("Your total price is $%.2f.\n\n", totalPrice);
```

I tried this, but it didn't work. I'm obviously missing something. I'm still pretty new to Java. Can someone help please?

```
switch (venue) {
    case venue:
    System.out.println("Rod Laver");
    totalPrice = 225.25 * numOfTickets;
    break;

    case 2:
    System.out.println("Margaret Court");
    totalPrice = 177.75 * numOfTickets;
    break;

    case 3:
    System.out.println("John Cain");
    totalPrice = 145.50 * numOfTickets;
    break;

    default:
    System.out.println("Invalid venue entered");
    break;
}

// Display the total price to the user
System.out.printf("\nHave a wonderful day at the %s venue.\n\n", venue);
System.out.printf("Your total price is $%.2f.\n\n", totalPrice);
```

Comment: I mean… venue seems to be a string in the first example, and… not so much in the second. It’s not clear why the change or what the specific problem is. Should also tag with the language, although I assume it’s Java.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. One basic issue is that you are doing a switch on `venue`, i.e., its value, with `switch (venue)`. The various `case` values after it are for its possible values. Thus, your first `case` statement, i.e., `case venue:` doesn't make any sense as it doesn't convey what particular value of `venue` it's supposed to be for. Also, as Dave's comment above indicates, it seems `venue` is a string, but some of your `case` values are for numbers instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use string in switch case in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240538/use-string-in-switch-case-in-java)

Comment: Putting aside the "switch" question, this code is unmaintainable since the ticket prices are hard coded, and any change would require the code to be recompiled and redeployed.  The correct approach is to use a `Map<String,BigDecimal>` to relate venues to their ticket prices, and read the values in from a file.  No `switch` would be needed in that case.  Maybe you'll learn how to do that in the next lesson.

Answer (score 3):

With Switch Expression (Java 14) we can do:

```java
double totalPrice = switch(venue) {
        case "Rod Laver" -> 225.25 * numOfTickets;
        case "Margaret Court" -> 177.75 * numOfTickets;
        case "John Cain"-> 145.50 * numOfTickets;
        case null, default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid venue: " + venue);
    };
```

The multiplication can also be moved outside the `switch`:

```java
double totalPrice = switch(venue) {
        case "Rod Laver" -> 225.25;
        case "Margaret Court" -> 177.75;
        case "John Cain"-> 145.50;
        case null, default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid venue: " + venue);
    } * numOfTickets;
```

<sub>if `case null` is removed, a NullPointerException will be thrown instead of the IllegalArgumentException in case `venue` is null</sub>

Comment: Yes, I was about to say: `double totalPrice = numOfTickets * switch(venue) {...};`

Answer (score 1):

If your venue information is static and baked into the code, you could always use an enum:

It might be overkill compared to a switch, but it is much easier to add or edit venues later on.

```java
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class VenueTicketPriceCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        double totalPrice = calculateTicketTotal("John Cain", 2);

        System.out.println(currencyFormatter.format(totalPrice)); // $291.00
    }

    static double calculateTicketTotal(String venueName, int numOfTickets) {
        if (venueName == null || venueName.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Venue name cannot be null or empty");
        }

        return Optional.of(venueName)
                .map(Venue::findByName)
                .map(Venue::getPrice)
                .map(price -> price * numOfTickets)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid venue name"));
    }

    enum Venue {
        ROD_LAVER("Rod Laver", 225.25),
        MARGARET_COURT("Margaret Court", 177.75),
        JOHN_CAIN("John Cain", 145.50);

        private static final Map<String, Venue> NAME_LOOKUP = new HashMap<>();

        static {
            for (Venue venue : Venue.values()) {
                NAME_LOOKUP.put(venue.getName(), venue);
            }
        }

        static Venue findByName(String name) {
            return NAME_LOOKUP.get(name);
        }

        private final String name;
        private final double price;

        Venue(String name, double price) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If ***venue*** it's a String variable you can make a switch like this :

```
double totalPrice = 0.0;
    switch(venue) {
        case "Rod Laver":
            totalPrice = 225.25 * numOfTickets;
            break;
        case "Margaret Court":
            totalPrice = 177.75 * numOfTickets;
            break;
        case "John Cain":
            totalPrice = 145.50 * numOfTickets;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid venue entered");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually figured it out about a minute after I posted this question. It just came to me after looking at the code for a bit.