# What is the meaning of "Enum in java are set of predefined constants"?

Tags: java, enums

**When you say enums are constant in java, what do you actually mean?**

What type of constant(**integer constant , char constant, string constant**) are they?

Why Java system is not complaining when I use enums as switch cases value?

As for as i know prior to 1.7 switch statement accepts byte, short, int or char as case value. So when someone say enum are constant and they can be used in switch cases, what type of constant they mean because switch accepts only byte, short, int or char

For example String constants, they are added in java 1.7 but enum are there since 1.5 and they are being used in switch cases value and now from Java 1.7 on words I can use String as switch case value?

How does Java handles enum in switch cases, does it use **ordinal()** value of enums?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387329/using-string-representations-of-enum-values-in-switch-case and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html That should help

Comment: @FlightOdyssey Actually what you have pointed is exactly opposite of what i asked? but that is good,  probably i would have thought that after clearing this current doubt?

Comment: Specifically the enum is a class that extends java.lang.Enum and the constants are static instances of that class. It is just a special syntax to do basically normal Java stuff. They are probably compared in a switch as an integer. Somebody who knows more can correct me if I'm wrong since I am inferring a bit but that's basically how it works.

Comment: @aliasm2k I have gone through that link at least five time and that link did not answer my question?

Comment: What *is* your question? It's impossible to understand what it is you don't understand. The language you have quoted is perfectly clear.

Comment: @Radiodef  When you say  **They are probably compared as an integer** what do you mean? How can i get that integer value?

Comment: The private constructor for the enum class you declare (that you can't call in code but is called when you declare the enum constants) takes a String and the ordinal int as arguments. Enum implements Comparable and I *assume* they are compared on the ordinal value. I *assume* they are allowed in a switch as special syntax similar to the way that implementing Iterable allows for-each iteration. I can't find a resource to back that up exactly but I think it's a safe assumption.

Comment: @EJP As for as i know prior to 1.7 switch statement accepts byte, short, int or char as case value. So when someone say enum are constant and they can be used in switch cases, what type of constant they mean because switch accepts only byte, short, int or char?

Comment: Here's the language spec for enums: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9 I basically think you shouldn't worry about the switch comparison. It is almost certainly special syntax. Under the hood an enum is just a class with static instances of itself so switching on one could only be allowed out of some specialness.

Comment: @Radiodef i also assume the same. If i don't get any different answer then i will move on with the same assumption. Thank you for the help.

Comment: It's best to think of them with a concrete example, like colors. Imagine switching between red, green, blue, yellow, etc. Trying to convert them to strings or integers is meaningless. Under the covers I believe it is actually an identify comparison (`==`), since enums are guaranteed to have one and only one copy of each instance per JVM.

Comment: @geecatc You're wrong. It's as simple as that. Switch statements have accepted enums as well, since enums were introduced. Your question is self-contradictory.

Comment: @EJP ok i get it. Thank you for the help!! I did not knew that switch statements have accepted enum and also i read the concept from  a book and it was not mentioned there clearly. Now i get it. May be my understanding was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what your asking. Enums are constants because they cannot be changed during run time.

you can use a switch statement on them because there is a predefined number of elements so the compiler knows when all the cases have been covered.

Comment: so does that mean if I create a arraylist of 10 constant object i can use that list in switch statement?

Comment: no because the arraylist itself is not constant

Comment: yes arraylist is not constant but i was thinking about immutable List. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700971/immutable-array-in-java.   Ok now after reading about immutable List, i think now understand why i can not use list. but actual question remains **What type of constant are enum constant?**

Comment: I dont really know what you mean by that

Comment: I think i am trying to learn in more detail than required, Probably i should move on. Thank you for the help. i will wait some more and if there no different answer than yours, then i will accept your answer.