# java split strings function

Tags: java, string, split

I'm trying to build a program which reads a certain String after using the Split function

```
import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Lexa2 {

public void doit() {
    String str = "( 5 + 4 ) * 2";
    String [] temp = null;
    temp = str.split(" "); 
    dump(temp);
}
public void dump(String []s) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < s.length ; i++) {           
        if (s[i] == "(") {              
            System.out.println("This is the left paren");
        } else if (s[i] == ")"){                
            System.out.println("This is the right paren");          
        }else  if (s[i] == "+"){                
            System.out.println("This is the add");          
        }else  if (s[i] == "-"){                
            System.out.println("This is the sub");          
        }else  if (s[i] == "*"){                
            System.out.println("This is the mult");         
        }else  if (s[i] == "/"){                
            System.out.println("This is the div");          
        }else               
            System.out.println("This is a number");
    }
}   

     public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
       Lexa2 ss = new Lexa2();
         ss.doit();
 }
    }
```

The output should be something like this:

```
This is the left paren
this is a number
this is the add
this is the right paren
this is a number
```

Comment: So, what is the question? Your code looks reasonable.

Comment: **DON'T USE == FOR STRING COMPARISON** I say it loudly because it has been repated so many times in a softer voice, maybe you need it.

Comment: [15.21 Equality Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java String.equals versus ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: Take a reference to a good Java book(s).

Answer (score 4):

you're pretty close, just replace `(s[i] == "?")` with `(s[i].equals("?"))`

Comment: Thanks i always mess up with the lamest mistakes :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `s[i] == ")"` to compare strings. In this way, you're not checking if the string in `s[i]` is equal to `)`.

Use the [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method. Then you can compare the strings using:

```
if (s[i].equals("("))
```

Replace `equals` in the other `if` statements.

**UPDATE**

P.S. I think the best way to compare strings, looking to your code, is to use the `switch/case` statements. But, this feature is [only available in Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html). I think this will avoid the continuous checking with `if` statements, and the code will be more readable. If you have Java 7, use this feature, otherwise, in case of Java 6 or lower, follow @pstanton suggestion. ;-)

Comment: switches don't work with strings, so he/she would need to use char

Comment: @pstanton You're right, indeed this feature is available only in Java 7. Thank you :-) Answer updated! For further info, take a look to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java