# Java, "pointer" equality and string comparison

Tags: java, string, pointers, reference, equality

I've C code that use a lot of commands identified by static string constants.

```
static char* KCmdA = "commandA"
static char* KCmdB = "commandB"
static char* KCmdC = "commandC"
```

In C I can compare two strings with strcmp(A, B) for example but as I only refer those command via their static string identifier it's faster to only check for pointer inequality since I know my unknowCMD can only be a pointer to one of my static strings.

```
switch(unknowCMD)
{
    case KCmdA:
    ...
    case KCmdB:
    ...
}
```

I guess in Java the equivalent to strcmp would be the method equals:

```
unknowCMD.equals(KCmdA)
```

Is there an equivalent of the pointer equality in Java ? I know Java uses only references. Is it possible to use those references for equality test without actually comparing the strings ?

Sorry if this is obvious I've check the doc but did not find any definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the way you are using static strings here it would be better to use Enums.
You can compare them by using .equals and ==.
You can use enums in switch case too.

Comment: Indeed. I actually did not use them because I read somewhere that it was not recommended on Android. But it would actually probably be the best approach for my problem. I'll be able to use a switch statement with enums.

Answer (score 6):

if you compare equality of string refrences Use `==`

```
if(str1==str2){

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `==`, but it's dangerous and brittle.

Note that for `String`s, the first thing `equals()` does is test equality of the references, so you're not buying much by doing this.

Comment: wow that was a fast answer. OK so equals does not actually compare the string content that's good to now. That actually make me though of a related problem. How can I use a switch statement for comparing strings ?

Comment: You need Java SE 7 for that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java

Comment: What ?! it's only a recent feature ? I'm developing for Android so I won't be able to use it. Anyway thanks a lot to both of you.