# java string.contains in switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

How can I convert the following code to switch statement?

```
String x = "user input";

if (x.contains("A")) {
    //condition A;
} else if (x.contains("B")) {
    //condition B;
} else if(x.contains("C")) {
    //condition C;
} else {
    //condition D;
}
```

Comment: There is no other way to write this, unless there is same behavior for a number of containment conditions.

Comment: The [switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement.

Comment: Switch switches on finite values.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a way, but not using `contains`. You need a regex.

```
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[ABCD]").matcher("aoeuaAaoe");
if (m.find())
  switch (m.group().charAt(0)) {
  case 'A': break;
  case 'B': break;
  }
```

Comment: works only if the conditions are limited to **"[ABCD]"**, wont work if I want to check for a random letter or word

Comment: No exactly readable and intuitive, but it does the job! It could be abstracted away to commented method with a good descriptive name, then it would be just nice.

Comment: @Slanec Intuitiveness is totally in the eye of the beholder. To a non-programmer, no line of code in any programming language is intuitive. To someone who codes everyday with regex's, this is a direct and obvious solution.

Comment: good one. just like Sangeet mentioned, if i wanna do longer words or sentences, it might need some improvements, but still

Comment: Kiddo, in Java 7 you are covered for longer strings, the regex syntax is only sligthly different.

Comment: The problem i am seeing with this is that in the original question is creating a scenario where you are searching for multiple constant strings within 1 variable. As Sangeet mentioned in this solution it only allows you to do 1 type of search

Comment: @hfrog713 Not sure I follow you... but you can use this technique to search for any set of strings you choose. `Pattern.compile("search|for|any|of|these")` and `switch (m.group()) { case "search": case "for": ...)`

Comment: `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.` Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 9):

You can't `switch` on conditions like `x.contains()`. Java 7 supports `switch` on Strings but not like you want it. Use `if` etc.

Answer (score 5):

Condition matching is not allowed in java in switch statements.

What you can do here is create an **enum** of your string literals, and using that enum create a **helper function** which returns the matched enum literal. Using that value of enum returned, you can easily apply **switch case**.
For example:

```
public enum Tags{
   A("a"),
   B("b"),
   C("c"),
   D("d");

   private String tag;

   private Tags(String tag)
   {
      this.tag=tag;
   }

   public String getTag(){
      return this.tag;
   }

   public static Tags ifContains(String line){
       for(Tags enumValue:values()){
         if(line.contains(enumValue)){
           return enumValue;
         }
       }
       return null;
   }

}
```

And inside your java matching class,do something like:

```
Tags matchedValue=Tags.ifContains("A");
if(matchedValue!=null){
    switch(matchedValue){
       case A:
         break;
       etc...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@Test
public void test_try() {
    String x = "userInputA"; // -- test for condition A
    String[] keys = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
    String[] values = {"conditionA", "conditionB", "conditionC", "conditionD"};

    String match = "default";
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (x.contains(keys[i])) {
            match = values[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    switch (match) {
        case "conditionA":
            System.out.println("some code for A");
            break;
        case "conditionB":
            System.out.println("some code for B");
            break;
        case "conditionC":
            System.out.println("some code for C");
            break;
        case "conditionD":
            System.out.println("some code for D");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("some code for default");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
some code for A
```

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot use the `switch` with conditions

The JAVA 7 allows `String` to be used with `switch case`

[Why can't I switch on a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java)

**But conditions cannot be used with switch**

Answer (score 2):

you can only compare the whole word in switch.
For your scenario it is better to use if

Answer (score 1):

also HashMap:

```
String SomeString = "gtgtdddgtgtg";

Map<String, Integer> items = new HashMap<>();
items.put("aaa", 0);
items.put("bbb", 1);
items.put("ccc", 2);
items.put("ddd", 2);

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> item : items.entrySet()) {
    if (SomeString.contains(item.getKey())) {
        switch (item.getValue()) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("do aaa");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("do bbb");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("do ccc&ddd");
                break;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```