# Android - String Array with switch statement

Tags: android, switch-statement, arrays

I am looking for a guide as to how i can implement switch that would get values from a string array. Basically, i have a spinner with all the items as stated in my array, so i want to implement a switch so that whenever i click on an item, it will trigger an event, for example, going to another activity.

```
<string-array name="location1">

    <item>string a</item>
    <item>string a</item>
    <item>string b</item>
    <item>string c</item>
    <item>string d</item>

</string-array>
```

So, if i have a string array like this, how should I implement my switch statement?

Comment: You cannot use switch on strings before JDK 7. I am not sure I understand your question. Can you tell us more about what you want to do? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java )

Comment: @Romain Guidoux Oh :/ well basically i have a spinner with all the items as stated in my array, so i want to implement a switch so that whenever i click on an item, it will trigger an event, for example, going to another activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If array is:

```
<string-array name="cars_array">
    <item>Audi</item>
    <item>Ferrari</item>
</string-array>
```

You can access them like this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] cars = res.getStringArray(R.array.cars_array);
```

then you can access them individually as cars[0], cars[1] etc

If you want to access the same string resource as part of an array and individually as well, then you can do this:

```
<string name="audi">Audi</string>
<string name="ferrari">Ferrari</string>

<string-array name="cars_array">
    <item>@string/audi</item>
    <item>@string/ferrari</item>
</string-array>
```

Then you can simply say "@string/audi" to get it individually as well as you can use the array name "@string/cars" to use the string array as a whole.

Answer (score -1):

I think this resource on Android Developers site might help you : [String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

It will get you something like that :

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] strArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.location1);
```

Comment: Array is not even a collections class in Java.