# Switch with string in Java1.6

Tags: java, switch-statement, java-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switch Statement with Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java)

Im using the following code and I wonder if there is a way to do it with switch ,
the reason that I don't use it as default since type name is type string.(I know that this option is supported in 1.7 version but I need to use 1.6)
There is a way to overcome this problem ?

```
public static SwitchInputType<?> switchInput(String typeName) {

        if (typeName.equals("Binary")) {
            return new SwitchInputType<Byte>(new Byte("23ABFF"));
        }
        else if (typeName.equals("Decimal")) {
            return new SwitchInputType<BigDecimal>(new BigDecimal("A"));
        }
        else if (typeName.equals("Boolean")) {
            return new SwitchInputType<Boolean>(new Boolean("true"));
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this with value off as explained here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/338230/637889 has a **Before JDK 7** section with an example using the `enum` type

Comment: Actually this answer is the duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in other answers, you can't use switch statement with strings if you're working with Java 1.6.

The best thing to do is to use an enumerator instead of string values:

```
public static SwitchInputType<?> switchInput(InputType type) {
    switch(type){
        BINARY:
            return new SwitchInputType<Byte>(new Byte("23ABFF"));
        DECIMAL:
            return new SwitchInputType<BigDecimal>(new BigDecimal("A"));
        BOOLEAN:
            return new SwitchInputType<Boolean>(new Boolean("true"));
    }
}
```

where:

```
public enum InputType{
    BINARY, DECIMAL, BOOLEAN // etc.
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In your `Field` class add an `InputType fieldType` property. Then inside the loop:

```
MemberTypeRouting.switchInput(field.getFieldType());
```

Comment: Thanks but here you write BINARY, DECIMAL, BOOLEAN in upper case and I should get the like Boolean Binary and etc ... In addition I get String like Edm.Int16 Edm.Boolean etc so how should I handle it?

Comment: If you can't change your code replacing returned string values with enum values, you can't use switch statement...

Comment: If I want to do it how should I try?

Comment: can you post the code of the metod is returning these `typeName` strings?

Comment: for (Field field : declaredFields) {
     
String memberName = field.getName();
witchInputType<?> switchInput = MemberTypeRouting.switchInput(fieldTypeName

Comment: I updated my answer, but post your code in the original question, so that others can see that.

Answer (score 2):

Switches with Strings are only supported since Java 7. Sadly it was not supported in older versions, so you cannot use it wit Java 6, and you'll have to stay with the if/else statements you are already using.

See also this question, asked a few years back:
[Why can't I switch on a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java)

Comment: what does it mean that I need to create class (ENUN)with all the expected values and than ask for them?