# Functionality of SWITCH Statement

Tags: java, javascript

**How do you use the switch statement in Java?**  I'm a complete beginner.

I've worked with Javascript when designing web sites, so I have some very basic programming experience.

Comment: Isn't BlueJ a Java Ide? So, that is Java...

Comment: I found this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java

Comment: whoaa, that's too complected for me, can any one give a simple example??

Answer (score 1):

> but when I'm writing codes in this software I feel something similar to JAVA coding

That is because you are writing Java, since BlueJ is nothing that an IDE for Java, not a language.
So, answering your question, if you want a switch statement, write a Java switch statement:

```
switch (variable) {
    case option1:
        //code
    break;
    case option2:
        //other code
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you guys for telling me that BLUEJ is an IDE for JAVA, then I started searching for JAVA **switch statement**.

I found an article with simple examples that would explain to any beginner like me what is SWITCH statement.

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_switch_statements.html

Thanks everyone for your answers and valuable time.

Comment: Btw, it's "Java" not "JAVA." It's not an acronym, just a plain ol' name.