# Can Eclipse convert if statements to if-else-if

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

I'm using Java with Eclipse.

In my application, one code snippet is there which is the long series of multiple `if statements`.

Recently I had to work upon that code & I found that these multiple `if statements` can be converted to `if-else-if` ladder.

Now converting this to `if-else-if` ladder manually is somewhat cumbersome.

Is there some short cut in Eclipse that I can use to do so?

Comment: This code sounds a bit messy. Have you considered refactoring it to remove some of the if statements? That might be a better approach for you and those who come after you.

Comment: I don't think there is. If copy/pasting an `else` in front of every of your `if` is considered too much work, there is something seriously wrong with your code ;-)

Comment: There is a big difference between series of `if` and an `if-else-if` ladder . Hope you know it ? It depends on logic what needs to be used . They are not equivalent .

Comment: Well, consecutive `if` statements can't necessarily be replaced by `if-elseif` ones, and as this is a very specific need I doubt there's any functionality to do that.

Comment: Use Find/Replace Dialog. Replace all `}\s*if` with `}else if`. Enable "Regular Expressions". You can select the lines you want and enable "Selected lines".

Comment: @MarkChorley Yes it is messy. I'm refactoring it. And as a part of the refactoring, I need to convert it into if-else if ladder.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Yes I know the difference.

Comment: @stonedsquirrel, there are 50 if statements. copy-paste is the last option I would prefer.

Comment: @RAS adding else ifs wouldn't be my first step under most circumstances. I think it's time you let the dog see the rabbit. Post your code

Comment: @johnchen902, can you please post it as answer?

Comment: @RAS Done. Also add a picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long search I finally found the short cut in Eclipse.

I selected all the `if statements`, pressed `Ctrl+1 (Right Click & selected Quick Fix)`.

It gave me an option "`Join if sequence in if-else-if`", which does exactly what I want.

Comment: Oh cool. I almost didn't see this answer, I'd suggest you un-accept the currently accepted answer and accept this one instead.

Comment: @MikeFHay I know this is the actual answer I was looking for. But I've accepted john's answer as it was a nice answer when I had to solve the issue on urgent basis. This solution I've found later. So I think johnchen902's answer deserves the acceptance.

Comment: @RAS Your answer is better. Mine is just a hack and won't work if there are nested `if`. Please accept your answer instead.

Answer (score 4):

- Use Find/Replace Dialog.
- Replace all `}\s*if` with `}else if`.
- Enable "Regular Expressions".
- You can select the lines you want and enable "Selected lines".

[image]

Comment: I be damned if I didn't try to close this dialog window to see the full answer...

Answer (score 1):

Find & Replace all "if" with "else if", then fix the compiler error on the first one by deleting the "else". Make sure you're not accidentally changing anything else that you shouldn't!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, +1 from my side. But I think john's answer requires less manual effort.

Answer (score 1):

Since it might not be the same logic, I don't think that Eclipse has that feature. I do know that IntelliJ have Inspections covering those kind of issues, so maybe a plugin doing code inspections can help you refactor.

Secondly, if it can be converted to `if else if`, then it might also be convertable to `switch case` depending on what variable you are looking at, and if it's the same. Also available on strings since java 7. It might also be refactorable to do switch on `enums`.

Comment: I cannot convert it to switch case because the operation is performed on String & I'm using Java 6.

Comment: You might also consider Enums

Comment: @RAS as Vixen suggests, if you are limited to a version before Java 7, you convert your Strings to Enums. The accepted answer [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java) explains this rather well.

Comment: @zEro Ok I got the point. I'll convert the strings to enums as a part of code refactoring.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, +1 from my side. But I think john's answer requires less manual effort.

Comment: @RAS the effort might be worth it if the results give you better quality and easier maintainability of the code

Comment: @Vixen and your answer does that. I'll definitely use Enums & switch.