# Does Java 7 switch statement with String use equals() method?

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, equals

Java 7 supports switching with `Strings` like the code below

```
switch (month.toLowerCase()) {
case "january":
    monthNumber = 1;
    break;
case "february":
    monthNumber = 2;
    break;
default: 
    monthNumber = 0;
    break;
}
```

Does Java call the `equals()` method on each `String` case? Or it relies on `==` or `intern()`?

Is this simply equivalent to:

```
String month = month.toLowerCase();
if("january".equals(month)){
monthNumber = 1;
}else if("february".equals(month)){
monthNumber = 1;
}..
```

UPDATE:

> The String in the switch expression is compared with the expressions
>   associated with each case label **as if** the `String.equals` method were
>   being used.

As the docs point out that the behavior is as if `equals()` is called.

Comment: 1) I should think that it would have to, since it doesn't make sense if it didn't, does it? 2) Have you looked at the source code?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - It could use `==` and rely on `intern` - but I would think that would break in many cases.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: too risky, I would think.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon yes basically that was the reason I asked the question :)

Comment: Interesting answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) say

```
The String in the switch expression is compared with the expressions associated
with each case label as if the String.equals method were being used.
```

Since it says **as if** my guess would be it does not though the internal implementation would be the same as .equals() method.

Comment: Is there any other mechanism which a compiler could use which wouldn't rely upon details of string implementation which future implementations would be allowed to change, other than perhaps pre-checking reference equality before the virtual method call [and perhaps even before hashing?]

Answer (score 13):

The Java 7 switch statement actually generates bytecode that uses both the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods. The hash code is used to generate faster switch lookups; i.e. to avoid a chain of equals checks like you would get with an if-else chain.

Comment: Does it ever test for reference equality before computing the hash code?  I would guess that it would be pretty common that a switch value would be reference-equal to one of the switch labels.

Comment: No, I don't think so. It seems to compute the hashcode first, jump to section with String's for that hashcode and then check equals on those Strings (usually only one).

Comment: Interesting.  I would think that strings given to a `switch` statement would be literals more than half the time, although I guess the hashing could still be a win *if* either a hash code has been computed already *or* it will be needed in future.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

> "The switch statement when used with a String uses the equals() method
>   to compare the given expression to each value in the case statement
>   and is therefore case-sensitive and will throw a NullPointerException
>   if the expression is null."

http://java.dzone.com/articles/new-java-7-feature-string

Comment: Because some random blog post says it does not necessarily mean it is correct.

Comment: I did actually research a fair bit on this subject, my answer just contained one of the resources I used.

Answer (score 6):

The `switch` statement when used with a `String` uses the `equals()` method to compare the given expression to each value in the `case` statement and is therefore case-sensitive and will throw a `NullPointerException` if the expression is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful aticle that explains [how switch over string is implemented in Java 7](http://www.coolcoder.in/2011/08/features-from-java-7-that-you-will-love.html)