# How can we do switch case using string

Tags: java

```
public class SwitchExampleString
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String choice;
        switch(args)
        {
            case "day1" :
                choice="Sunday";
                System.out.println(choice);
                break;
            case "day2" :
                choice="Monday";
                System.out.println(choice);
                break;
            case "day3" :
                choice="Tuesday";
                System.out.println(choice);
                break;
            case "day4" :
                choice="Wednesday";
                System.out.println(choice);
                break;
            case "day5" :
                choice="Thursday";
                System.out.println(choice);
                break;
            case "day6" :
                choice="Friday";
                System.out.println(choice);
                break;
            case "day7" :
                choice="Saturday";
                System.out.println(choice);
                break;
            default :
                System.out.println("Wrong choice");
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me,i want to know how to use a string inside a switch(). The above shown is the program i had done so far. But it is showing errors. The java version which i have installed is jdk6.

Comment: just install jdk7.. java 6 doesn't allow string in switch operation, but from java 7, you can do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch Statement with Strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java)

Comment: You are switching on `String[]` instead of `String`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are switching on a String **array** not a String...

```
switch(args[0])
```

Would work - given you are using **JDK7**... And there is an argument supplied to your program - otherwise you'd get a nice `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`...

Answer (score 0):

`Switch` with `String` was introduced in JDK version 7 . So you need to upgrade to jdk7.

Comment: May i know the reason of downvote?  Op has mentioned the jdk version in use is 6.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `choice`  or `args[0]`

```
public class SwitchExampleString
{

public static void main(String args[])

{
    String choice="day1";
    switch(choice)
    {
case "day1" :
    choice="Sunday";
        System.out.println(choice);
    break;
case "day2" :
    choice="Monday";
        System.out.println(choice);
    break;
case "day3" :
    choice="Tuesday";
        System.out.println(choice);
    break;
case "day4" :
    choice="Wednesday";
        System.out.println(choice);
    break;
case "day5" :
    choice="Thursday";
        System.out.println(choice);
    break;
case "day6" :
    choice="Friday";
        System.out.println(choice);
    break;
case "day7" :
    choice="Saturday";
        System.out.println(choice);
    break;
    default :
System.out.println("Wrong choice");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to do it *one* string from the arguments, not all of them.

```
switch (args[0]) {
    case "day1" :
       //...
```

Practically, if you're decoding days you should put that logic in a parsing class -- and probably wouldn't encode them as dayN either. Consider case-insensitivity, as well:

Hopefully that's just your test usecase.. not real design.

With case-insensitivity (forcing to lowercase):

```
switch (args[0].toLowerCase()) {
    case "day1" :
       //...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the JDK 7 release, you can use a String object in the expression of a switch statement:

```
public String getTypeOfDayWithSwitchStatement(String dayOfWeekArg) {
     String typeOfDay;
     switch (dayOfWeekArg) {
         case "Monday":
             typeOfDay = "Start of work week";
             break;
         case "Tuesday":
         case "Wednesday":
         case "Thursday":
             typeOfDay = "Midweek";
             break;
         case "Friday":
             typeOfDay = "End of work week";
             break;
         case "Saturday":
         case "Sunday":
             typeOfDay = "Weekend";
             break;
         default:
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid day of the week: " + dayOfWeekArg);
     }
     return typeOfDay;
}
```

The switch statement compares the String object in its expression with the expressions associated with each case label as if it were using the String.equals method; consequently, the comparison of String objects in switch statements is case sensitive. The Java compiler generates generally more efficient bytecode from switch statements that use String objects than from chained if-then-else statements.

for more info click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html)

Answer (score 0):

strings in switch statements which is recently added feature in Java SE 7.

Using JDK 7, you can pass string as expression in switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch with String also, however you're trying to use a String array. Pick one argument which you want and use it as the String in the switch.

For example:

```
String yourChoice = args[0];

switch(yourChoice)
{
    case "something":
        System.out.print("this");
    case "somethingElse":
        System.out.print("that");
}
```

Also you have to use Java7 or newer and you have to ensure that args[0] isn't null - you have to input an argument when you run your JAR.

Answer (score 0):

search on **project coin**, you will get more info on this. or you can goto simply here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-7-%E2%80%93-project-coin-feature dzone, tutorial.

and you can download java 7 from here:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html