# Scanner requires int error. (Switch-case)

Tags: java, int, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class G2Ex3 {
public static void main (String args[]) {

Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Enter password: ");
String pw = in.nextLine();

switch (pw) {
case "JRU":
case "jru":
System.out.println("Password Accepted!");
break;
default:
System.out.println("Invalid Password!");
}
}
```

}

My code, as you can see has nothing to do with integers. My question is why does the program keeps telling me that it only founds java.lang.String and that it requires int? Thank you.

Comment: What version of Java? You couldn't use switch with string(s) prior to Java 7.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/338230/335858).

Comment: In case of passwords, I really recommend the use of char. It's a bit better than string, and you can use switch-case with it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Frisch, I really do think its because of the version of the Java I'm using. By the way, thanks for the answer @iWumbo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `switch` over `String`, unless you're using Java 7.

In Java 6 or lower, allowed arguments to `switch` are: `int`, `char`, `short`, `byte` or an `Enum`.

Comment: you can use it with jdk 7.

Comment: I've tried using char and it too don't work. I guess I have to switch to the higher version of Java then. Thank you!

Comment: @MichałRybak I've changed the - case "JRU": , into - case 'JRU' because its a chartype. But why does it still gives me the error?

Comment: `char` type contains a single character, therefore 'JRU' is not a valid `char`. I suggest reading more about [types in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) to get a solid base before trying to write more complex code.

Comment: check your java version.  http://www.java.com/en/download/help/version_manual.xml

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but how will use it? I've looked for examples on the internet, but its too complicated to follow