# Switch statement of string

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I'm trying to use a `switch` statement in a Android Application. This `switch` statement is testing the value of a `String`, and then based of that changing the value of another String.

String s1 = "a"
then
String s2 = "1"

I keep getting an error that says I need to change the compliance to 1.7. After I do that, I then get an error that says I need to change the compliance to 1.6.

Is there a way to fix this? or can anyone think of a work around for this?

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: You can't switch on strings pre-java 7. What Java version do you have? And what is your code exactly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java. I guess android still does not support java 7

Comment: Before Java 7 (not yet supported by Android) you can use switch only to compare integers... :(
This is not Visual Basic!

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Using-sourceCompatibility-1.7. As of build tools 19 java 7 is supported

Comment: well, I updated everything and its still not working. But I know my version of Java supports it because I was able to use strings in switch statements when doing this a a regular Java App, so... I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java does not support String in switch/case earlier java 7. But if you use java 6 you can achieve the desired result by using an enum.

```
private enum Fruit {
apple, carrot, mango, orange;
}

String value; // assume input
Fruit fruit = Fruit.valueOf(value); // surround with try/catch

switch(fruit) {
    case apple:
        method1;
        break;
    case carrot:
        method2;
        break;
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Enum constants should be UPPERCASE, as they are essentially `public static final` fields.

Comment: you are right, but i don't say how to programming, i give an idea how to solve this problem

Comment: check my question if it help you

Comment: while i didn't use this method, it did get to thinking: since I'm only looking for one letter that a user enters (I was only using string cause I found it to be easier) I could just convert the letter to it's ASCII value and base my switch statement off that.

Comment: @Just_Some_Guy Why not use the `char` itself?

Answer (score 1):

Using String comparison with [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) instead of switch on Strings (which is available in Java 7) could look like this:

```
//as an example, if s2 equals 'b'
String s2 = "b";

//this uses String's equals() method
if (s1.equals("a")) then {
    s2 = "1";
}
else if (s1.equals("b")) then {
    s2 = "2";
}
else {
    s2 = "3";
}
```

Of course, adapt the conditions to your needs.

Comment: Thanks! Im going to try this out next chance I get.

Answer (score 0):

donot use switch case but rather use if-else with string equals() method. it will help in code compatibility as switch with strings is only available with jdk 1.7+.

Comment: this was also giving me headaches when using strings, though I'm not sure what is meant by "string equals method()". Could you give a quick example of this?

Comment: sorry, I'm still ultra new at this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the below code in your pom.xml if in case it is a maven project.

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
```