# How to change if/else statement to switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I feel like an idiot not being able to figure this out.  Can someone please assist me in making this into a switch statement?

```
if (nextInput.equals("*"))
    f = new Fraction(f.times(f1));
else if (nextInput.equals("+"))
    f = new Fraction(f.times(f1));
else
    f = new Fraction(f.minus(f1));
```

Comment: [here you are](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: From java 7, you can use strings in swtich statment.For syntax read oracle documentation...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch Statement with Strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java)

Comment: switch (nextInput) { case "*": break; case "+": break; } etc...

Answer (score 4):

```
String text = "";

switch(text)
{
case "*":
   f = new Fraction(f.times(f1));
   break;
case "+":
   f = new Fraction(f.times(f1));
   break;
default :
  f = new Fraction(f.minus(f1));
}
```

`Switch` accept String in jdk 7 or higher

Answer (score 1):

Something like this you need

```
String x="";           
 switch(x)       
 {        
case "*":f = new Fraction(f.times(f1));break;        
case "+":f = new Fraction(f.times(f1));break;        
default:f = new Fraction(f.minus(f1));            
}
```

**Note**: switch Strings will only work in jdk7 and or higher versions

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation. Try this:

```
switch(nextInput){
    case "*":
        f = new Fraction(f.times(f1));
        break;
    case "+":
        f = new Fraction(f.times(f1));
        break;
    default:
        f = new Fraction(f.times(f1));
}
```