# Case Vs If-else in jdk7

Tags: java, if-statement, java-7

In jdk7, case statements accept Strings.
I have a scenario where i have to check if a String is present in list of strings and then perform operation.

```
Case "Car":
      syso("nice car");
      break;
case "bike":
      syso("nice bike");
      break;
default:
      syso("buy something");
```

or

```
if(stringList.contains("Car")){
syso("nice car");
}else if(stringList.contains("bike")){
syso{"nice bike");
}else{
syso{"buy something");
}
```

Till jdk6 case statements did not support Strings. 
What can be main advantages of this new feature however the same thing can be implemented using if-else..?

Comment: Hmm, given what you want to do, I don't see how a switch statement helps here

Comment: Another SO question in regards to the `switch` statement with `String` .. old, but the answer is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. **readability**. a switch statement becomes A LOT more readable as the number of cases goes up compared to the equivalent if-else chain
2. **performance**. though not as important as the previous point, switch statements can be compiled into faster code than if-else chains.
3. **fall-through**. a lot less important than the previous two, and rare enough to be flagged as a warning by some IDE's/tools, there are still cases where you can benefit from a fall-through (==no break after a particular case). this ties into readability again.

Comment: +1 for readability. I care less about the minute performance gain.

Comment: I have a doubt in your 2nd point. Performance depends on if its used in any loop or not. I think if-else gives better performance if run in loop.

Comment: @MithunKhatri - if you read up on it here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java) you'll see that switching on strings is basically composed of 2 steps - "hash-code"ing the string and then switching by hashcode (im simplifying). this means that it scales much better than a long chain of if-elses (jump table instead of a long sequence of compare-and-jump ops)

Comment: @radai until Java 7 (not sure in Java 8) switch does not use a jump table for small amounts of cases (< 18). Your other points still stand.

Comment: @assylias - i know. thats why i said "scales much better". for a small set of options it might very well be slower