# How to use String[] inputs in switch case in Android?

Tags: java, switch-statement, arrays

How to use the inputs of string array in switch case?

```
String[] mon=new String[]{"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};

switch (mon)
{
    case "January":
        m=1;
        break;
    case "February":
        m=1;
        break;                  
}
```

Comment: You can't use array in a switch statement.

Comment: What you're talking about doesn't seem logical. You initialize an array with all these values and then "switch" them? *And* you have the same statements in both "January" *and* "February"?? Think about it...the array has all these values; so what is it switching???

Comment: How can you check array object in switch?

Answer (score 7):

Java (before version 7) does not support String in `switch` case. But you can achieve the desired result by using an `enum`.

```
private enum Mon {
   January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December
};

String value; // assume input
Mon mon = Mon.valueOf(value); // surround with try/catch

switch(mon) {
    case January:
        m=1;
        break;
    case February:
        m2;
        break;
    // etc...
}
```

Please see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java) for more info

Comment: What is `fruit` here - `switch(fruit)`?

Comment: You probably wrote a good answer, but where does the `fruit` variable come from?

Comment: Funny, I thought `fruit` was a purposeful distraction.

Comment: @11684 I had similar problem earlier,and fruit was in my code,just typo.

Answer (score 2):

Since JDK 7 you can have a `String` in a `switch`. but **not** a String array....

[here's an example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html)

in your code, you're trying to put the whole array into the switch.
try this:

```
String[] mon=new String[]{"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
String thisMonth = mon[5];
    switch (thisMonth)
    {
        case "January":
            m=1;
            break;
        case "February":
            m=2;
            break;
...
        case "June":
            m=6;
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an array in a switch statement (before Java 7). If you are using Java 6 for Android development, you cannot switch on Strings either. Its better you use an enumeration for the months, then switch on the enumeration.

Comment: Strings in switches doesn't occur until 7, so yes *any* "Java" development cannot contain these prior to that. None of that was stated.