# I'm trying to write a simple switch statement

Tags: java

I know this not going to compile and run at this point.  However is the switch statement right? I did get a compiler error of: class, interface, or enum expected

```
public class Fruit
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

String choice = " ";

    switch(choice)
    {
    case " A ":  System.out.print(" Apple");
      break;

    case  " K ": System.out.println("Kiwi");
      break;

    case " P ": System.out.println("Pear");
      break;

    default: System.out.println("incorrect choice");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can not switch over string apparently  Here is a big discussion on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/why-cant-i-switch-on-a-string

Comment: Your code syntax is correct. You might want to check the version of Java that you're using; try updating the Java development kit.

Comment: My version is JDK 7.0_25

Answer (score 5):

You are getting the error because you must be trying to use `switch` with `String` with Java version lower than 7. `String` support for `switch` statement was introduced in Java 7 and hence you need to be on the same version or higher to compile your code.

Follow this tech note to learn more about switch with String:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Comment: In my experience, it is semi rare to need to switch on a string.  It might be prudent to rethink why you are trying to switch on a string and to consider using something like an Enum instead.

Comment: I agree. Don't switch on a string. In this case it looks like you should be switching on a char, which has always been allowed.

Answer (score 0):

**Strings in switch Statements**

In the JDK 7 release, you can use a `String` object in the expression of a `switch` statement.

The `switch` statement compares the String object in its expression with the expressions associated with each case label as if it were using the `String.equals` method; consequently, the comparison of String objects in switch statements is case sensitive. The Java compiler generates generally more efficient bytecode from `switch` statements that use `String` objects than from chained `if-then-else` statements.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can use a string as an expression of a case statement only with Java 7 or higher. If you can use only lower versions, then here is a work around for your code.

1. An alphabet has a number representation. That is, CHARACTERS have fixed number codes for them - http://www.kerryr.net/pioneers/ascii2.htm
2. You will get a String, get the first char in the string and then convert that char to its int code.
3. Use int code instead of String choice in the old fashioned switch.

   ```
   public class Fruit {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       String choice = "";
       int code = -1;

       choice = "K";
       code = (int) choice.charAt(0);

       switch (code) {
       case 65://A
           System.out.print("Apple");
           break;

       case 75://K
           System.out.println("Kiwi");
           break;

       case 80://P
           System.out.println("Pear");
           break;

       default:
           System.out.println("incorrect choice");
       }
     }
   }
   ```