# Java Switch basics

Tags: java

Hi is it possible to use a string in a switch statement or does it require a numeric value.  For example,

```
Switch (legs){case "Nice:" return "A nice person"}
```

Is this executable code?

Comment: Have you tried it out to see what happens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I switch on a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/why-cant-i-switch-on-a-string)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible starting in Java 7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In Java 7 and up, but your syntax is a little off. Something like this,

```
String legs = "Nice:";
switch (legs) {
case "Nice:":
    System.out.println("A nice person");
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("Not a nice person");
    break;
}
```

Output is

```
A nice person
```