# how to choose one view out of many in controller ( i don't want if/else because i might have many views)

Tags: java, model-view-controller, controllers

```
if ( accountType = "admin" )
        return admin view
if ( accountType = "customer" )
        return customer view
if ( accountType = "user" )
        return user view
if ( accountType = "merketing" )
        return marketing view
```

and so on .......

Comment: Use a Switch statement: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: @BakedInhalf switch does not operate on string types until java 7

Comment: @Funtik Sure you can! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/why-cant-i-switch-on-a-string

Comment: any one line solution?

Comment: @Funtik Yes switch operates on String after java 7 [see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html)

Comment: @ArslanKhan: Instead of having one controller and switching there, you might want to have multiple, more simple controllers for each account type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a map where you register your views with the given key:

```
viewsMap.put("admin", admin_view);
viewsMap.put("customer", customer_view);
...
```

and then, just do:

```
View view = viewsMap.get(accountType);
if (view == null) {
    return error_view;
}
return view;
```

Comment: still there will be processing in maps i want one line solution and want open closed principal

Comment: I don't think it can be done in one line, kind of matching the value of accountType to a variable name or something like this. Using a map is the closest you can get: one line to retrieve it (if you do not do any error checking), and one line for each view to register.

Comment: i am kinda thinking putting it in DB then retrieve it concat it with base url. like
redirectTo (baseURL + role + ".jsp");

Comment: probably you should make your pseudo-code in the question a bit clearer. What do you want to return? a (complex?) view object, or just a String, for example a URL? It's really not clear from your question, especially as you don't say if and what framework you use. If it's just a string, I think Foolish had a nice solution he might post again.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it into HashMap and then just get it from there ;)

Comment: still there will be processing in maps i want one line solution and want open closed principal

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate the creation code, use a simplified factory:

```
class ViewFactory {
   public static View createView(String viewName)
   {
        if( viewName = admin )
            return new AdminView();

   }
}
```

You can do this is your views implement a common interface.