# Some errors when working with arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to get this to work but I keep getting errors, primarily

```
C:\Users\Carter\OneDrive\Documents\Programs\Assignment7\Assignment7.java:26: error: '.class' expected
       Quiz myQuiz = new Quiz(int count, String name);
                                  ^
C:\Users\Carter\OneDrive\Documents\Programs\Assignment7\Assignment7.java:26: error: ';' expected
       Quiz myQuiz = new Quiz(int count, String name);
                                               ^
C:\Users\Carter\OneDrive\Documents\Programs\Assignment7\Assignment7.java:26: error: not a statement
       Quiz myQuiz = new Quiz(int count, String name);
                                                ^
C:\Users\Carter\OneDrive\Documents\Programs\Assignment7\Assignment7.java:26: error: ';' expected
       Quiz myQuiz = new Quiz(int count, String name);
                                                    ^
4 errors
```

Any help would be much appreciated! What I posted is just the driver program, I can also post the class definition if necessary! Thanks in advance!

```
//Driver program
import java.util.*;

public class Assignment7
{

   public static void main (String[] args) {

       Quiz myQuiz = new Quiz(int count, String name);

       Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

       String choice;
       char command;

       // print the menu
       printMenu();

       do
       {
           // ask a user to choose a command
           System.out.println("\nPlease enter a command or type ?");
           choice = console.next().toLowerCase();
           command = choice.charAt(0);

           switch (command)
            {
                 case 'n':  //asks and prints the quiz size and name of student
                      System.out.println("n [Create a new Quiz]");
                      System.out.println("[Input the size of quizzes]: ");
                      scores.length = console.nextInt();
                      System.out.print(scores.length);
                      System.out.println("[Input the name of student]: ");
                      name = console.nextString();
                      System.out.print(name);

                      break;
                 case 'a': //  adds a score
                      System.out.println("a [Add a score]: ");
                      numAdd = console.nextInt();
                      System.out.print(numAdd);

                      break;
                 case 'd': // deletes a score
                      System.out.println("d [Delete a score]: ");
                      numDelete = console.nextInt();
                      System.out.print(numDelete);

                     break;

                case 'p': //prints the information
                    System.out.println("p [Print the information]: ");
                    System.out.println(name);
                    System.out.println(scores);
                      break;


                case '?':
                      printMenu();
                      break;

                case 'q':
                      break;


                default:
                       System.out.println("Invalid input");

            }

        } while (command != 'q');

    }  //end of the main method


   public static void printMenu()
   {
    System.out.print("\nCommand Options\n"
                   + "-----------------------------------\n"
                   + "n: Create a new data\n"
                   + "a: Add a score\n"
                   + "d: Delete a score\n"
                   + "p: Print the information\n"
                   + "?: display the menu again\n"
                   + "q: Quit this program\n\n");

    } // end of the printMenu method

}
```

Comment: `new Quiz(int count, String name);` - You need a lesson in basic method calling syntax.

Comment: Well I am in a first semester java class so...
And also, that is not calling a method, that is setting up the method object i am going to be using using the Quiz class.

Comment: How is `Quiz` defined? Do you want it to be the array you mention?

Comment: public class Quiz
{
 private int count;
 private String name;
 private int[] scores;

 public Quiz (int count, String name2)
 {
  count = 0;
  name = name2;
 }

Comment: In addition what version of Java are you using? Switch statements won't work on strings on older versions of Java (pre JDK 7). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/why-cant-i-switch-on-a-string

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define the count and name before you call

```
Quiz myQuiz = new Quiz(int count, String name);
```

In addition, you don't need int and string identifier before you construct a Quiz object.

So basically, your code should be like

```
int count = **;
String name = "***";
Quiz myQuiz = new Quiz(count,name);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call a method you don't need to specify the data types (only when defining a method)

e.g.

```
Quiz myQuiz = new Quiz(count, name);
//vs
Quiz myQuiz = new Quiz(int count, String name);
```

Since the data types are specified when you define the method, Java already knows what they are.  You only need to pass the values.

Comment: Well I've tried that but I get like 10 more errors.

Comment: The other errors are likely something different.  Try reading the errors to see if you can figure them out... or Google it.

Comment: Tried, i have like 30 minutes to finish this. Can I post them here maybe you could help ?

Comment: I hate to have to say this, but you need more than 30 minutes. I hope you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that will COMPILE--ONLY to give you an idea of syntax and declaration requirements--but it won't come close to doing what you want. Good luck.

```
package javaapplication75;

public class Quiz {

 int count; 
 String name; 
 int[] scores; 

 public Quiz (int count, String name2) 
 { 
     count = 0;       // Not sure why 0...
     name = name2; }
 }


package javaapplication75;

    import java.util.*;

    public class Assignment7
    {
  private static int numAdd;  // need to declare these two vars
  private static int numDelete;


       public static void main (String[] args) {

           Quiz myQuiz = new Quiz(5, "D"); // doesn't do anything good, but compiles

           Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

           String choice;
           char command;

           // print the menu
           printMenu();

           do
           {
               // ask a user to choose a command
               System.out.println("\nPlease enter a command or type ?");
               choice = console.next().toLowerCase();
               command = choice.charAt(0);

               switch (command)
                {
                     case 'n':  //asks and prints the quiz size and name of student
                          System.out.println("n [Create a new Quiz]");
                          System.out.println("[Input the size of quizzes]: ");
                          myQuiz.count = console.nextInt()
                              ;
                          System.out.print(myQuiz.scores.length);
                          System.out.println("[Input the name of student]: ");
                          myQuiz.name = console.nextLine();
                          System.out.print(myQuiz.name);

                          break;
                     case 'a': //  adds a score
                          System.out.println("a [Add a score]: ");
                          numAdd = console.nextInt();
                          System.out.print(numAdd);

                          break;
                     case 'd': // deletes a score
                          System.out.println("d [Delete a score]: ");
                          numDelete = console.nextInt();
                          System.out.print(numDelete);

                         break;

                    case 'p': //prints the information
                        System.out.println("p [Print the information]: ");
                        System.out.println(myQuiz.name);
                        System.out.println(myQuiz.scores);
                          break;


                    case '?':
                          printMenu();
                          break;

                    case 'q':
                          break;


                    default:
                           System.out.println("Invalid input");

                }

            } while (command != 'q');

        }  //end of the main method


       public static void printMenu()
       {
        System.out.print("\nCommand Options\n"
                       + "-----------------------------------\n"
                       + "n: Create a new data\n"
                       + "a: Add a score\n"
                       + "d: Delete a score\n"
                       + "p: Print the information\n"
                       + "?: display the menu again\n"
                       + "q: Quit this program\n\n");

        } // end of the printMenu method


    }
```