# Java with switch

Tags: java

i'm not entirely sure what is wrong with this java. i kept getting incompatible type when i run the program. I am only a beginner in java program. Please give me a hand in detail. i have tried various method and searched for many links in google. but i was just unfortunate.
Write a program that asks the user to enter “air”, “water”, or “steel”, and the distance that a sound wave will travel in the medium. The program should then display the amount of time it will take.

Prompts And Output . The program prompts for the medium with: "Enter one of the following: air, water, or steel: " and reads the medium. If the medium is not air, water or steel the program prints the message : "Sorry, you must enter air, water, or steel." an nothing else. Otherwise the program prompts for the distance with ("Enter the distance the sound wave will travel: " and reads it in and then prints "It will take x seconds." where x is the time calculated by your program .

and this is what I have so far.

```
class one{ 
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter one of the following: air, water, or steel: ");
        String text = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter the distance the sound wave will travel: ");

        double distance;
        double time;

        distance = input.nextDouble();

        switch (text){
            case "air":
                time = (distance/1100);
                System.out.println("It will take " + time + " sconds." );
                break;

            case "water":
                time = (distance/4900);
                System.out.println("It will take " + time + " seconds.");
                break;

            case "steel":
                time = (distance/16400);
                System.out.println("It will take " + time + " seconds.");
                break;


            default:
                System.out.println("Sorry, you must enter air, water, or steel.");
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: What error message did you get exactly? If it indicates a line number, please show which line that is.

Comment: I just ran it, and it seems work as intended. Please supply the exact input, as well as a copy of the error message.

Comment: Please specify what version of Java you are running it on.

Comment: Note that Java 7 was the first version where you can actually use strings in switch/case. Maybe you use the wrong compiler level?

Answer (score 2):

What version of Java are you using? Cannot use switch on a String in versions < Java 7. See [Why can't I switch on a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/why-cant-i-switch-on-a-string)

Also suggest you use something like Eclipse to code Java which will pick up these errors.

Comment: I just changed the compliance level in my Eclipse test project to 1.6, and got a very nice clear explanation of what was wrong with the switch.

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: @reformed I agree, but I didn't have enough points so I had to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

so your compiler might be lower version.. `switch` in `string` will not work in Java 6 and before.

upgrade your `JDK` to higher version. 
[Download latest JKD here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

in the [JDK 7 release](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html), you can use a String object in the expression of a switch statement:

Instead of using alternative like `if else`,

It would be better to upgrade your `JDK`.

***note***: `String` objects in `switch` statements is `case sensitive` so before comparing the string, you can make the inputted string to `uppercase` 'coz the switch statement is case sensitive.