# How do I rewrite if into switch with cases as strings in android app?

Tags: android, if-statement, switch-statement

I m detecting which button i clicked:

```
public void next_page(View view){

    //if else - works:

    if( view.getId() == "fly_button")        
            Log.d(LOG, " fly button clicked");
    else if (view.getId() == "imageButton") 
            Log.d(LOG, "image button clicked");

    //switch does not work:
   // every id is a string, how to show it as integer in "case"?

    switch(  view.getId()  ){
        case "fly_button":
            Log.d(LOG, "fly button clicked");
        case "imageButton":
            Log.d(LOG, "image button clicked");
    }
```

Comment: Do you want an enum?

Comment: Currently in Android you cannot switch on a String
<br>check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/why-cant-i-switch-on-a-string

Comment: Note that you cannot use `==` with strings since they are objects.  Because of string interning, your code *might* work sometimes but will fail often.  Instead, you should use `equals()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

switch(v.getId()){

  case R.id.Button1: 
    // statements
    break;

  case R.id.Button2:
    // statements
    break;
}
}
```

If this will not work try this:

```
int id = view.getId();
if (id == R.id.Button1) {
    action1();
} else if (id == R.id.Button2) {
    action2();
}
```