# getStringExtra in a switch?

Tags: android, android-intent, switch-statement

I have this code:

```
String Tunet = intent.getStringExtra("Tunet");

if (Tunet.equals("Yes")  ){
    tv22.setText(" okay");
} else {
    tv22.setText("please answer");
}
```

I want to do this code, in a switch statement, something like this but I don't know how.

```
switch(Tunet.equals)
case: Yes
   // do something
case: No
   // do something
case: I don't know
   // do something
```

and continue it like this, how to do this? Thanks for help.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `else if`

```
if (Tunet.equals("Yes")  ){
        tv22.setText(" okay");
    } else if (Tunet.equals("No")){
        tv22.setText("please answer");
    }  else if (Tunet.equals("I don't know ")){
        tv22.setText("TEXT");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are compiling your project with Java SE 7+, you can do switch directly on your String so this is a valid code

```
switch(Tunet){
    case "Yes":
    break;
    case "No":
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/why-cant-i-switch-on-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

here is a work around for your problem, may that help.

```
    String Tunet = intent.getStringExtra("Tunet");
    int _Case = -1;
    if (Tunet.equals("yes")) {

        _Case = 1;
    } else if(Tunet.equals("no")) {
        _Case = 2;
    }

    switch (_Case){
        case 1:
        // code if if Tunet is yes
            break;
        case 2:
            //code for no
            break;
    }
```

Comment: warning: unnecessary loop for the compiler .

Answer (score 1):

Before JDK 7 release it was not possible to use String as argument in switch. Oracle realized this shortcoming and if you are working on jdk 7.0+ , you can write the code as:

```
switch(Tunet.equals)
{
case: Yes
      // do something
      break;
case: No
      // do something
      break;
default: I don't know
      // do something
}
```

Comment: It won't but this is just the skeleton or the idea. Why would I write working code for free ;)

Comment: Don't know, but how can you just copy that code from the question and say it works in Java 7 when clearly it won't. Anyway, fair play for getting an upvote for this.

Answer (score 1):

From JDK 7.0 you can simply,

```
switch(intent.getStringExtra("Tunet")){
    case "A":
    break;

    default:
    break; 
}
```