# I'm having some trouble with my switch statement

Tags: java

Ok so I've been programming for a short time and I've already started making pretty nice programs. But when it comes to switches it's always luck when they actually work. I wrote this switch statement:

```
String answer1 = in.nextLine();

switch (answer1)
{
case 1:
        System.out.println("...");
        break;
case 2:
        System.out.println("...");
        break;
case 3:
        System.out.println("...");
        break;
}
```

And the switch labels next to the cases all said 'error cannot convert from int to string' could someone please help. Thanks 
 Noob programmer~ Chase

Comment: The code didn't actually looked so sandwiched together it's just my iphone doin that

Comment: If the code does not look right, you can click [edit] and change it.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to switch on a `String`, while the cases are `int`s. You need to parse the string before passing it to `switch`:

```
String answer1 = in.nextLine();
switch (Integer.parseInt(answer1)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings in switch are supported only from Java 7.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

If you are using Java 7 and above then

```
switch (answer1)
{
case "1":
        System.out.println("...");
        break;
case "2":
        System.out.println("...");
        break;
case "3":
        System.out.println("...");
        break;
```

else you have to convert it to int as shown in the answer by @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 0):

You might need to verify the version of Java you're using. This was not possible on older versions of Java.

See: [Why can't I switch on a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/why-cant-i-switch-on-a-string)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

That is, if you intend to switch on String. See the below answer (@dasblinkenlight) if you do indeed expect an integer (You need to parse it).