# How to navigate to another screen according to the text in editText?

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener

I want my app to be such that when the editText1 has value (2) without brackets in it, the button press (with onClick="k") would navigate to MainActivity2. And if the text is (3), the activity MainActivity3 would open.
I guess it'll use If function. How can I just implement this in my app?
Sorry for silly questions, I'm just a newbie. ;-;

Comment: (with onClick="k") -- what is k?.. button??.. or character in keyboard?..

Comment: @uday k is the android:onClick of my button.

Comment: can you post any code?

Comment: String string = editText1.getText().toString();{
 switch(string){

 case "2":
  public void kden(View v)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
      startActivity(i);
      
  }
 break;

 case "3":
  public void kden(View v)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity3.class);
      startActivity(i);
      
  }

@Mohit here's my code till now. It isn't working. It's showing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Within onClickListener, get the data from edittext as string and compare it using switch-case :

```
String string = editText1.getText().toString();
switch(string){

case "2":
//Start MainActivity2
break;

case "3":
//Start MainActivity3
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why exactly you're doing this, but here's what you can do:

1. Set the `EditText` property to accept only digits/numbers
2. `onClick()` of the button, access the number entered in EditText by

   `editText1.getText().toString()`
3. After you've done that, use `switch-case` statements to launch the
   desired activity.

Comment: Could you please elaborate it a bit more? I'm a beginner and can't really understand that. ._.

i've anyway typed this:  

String string = editText1.getText().toString();{
 switch(string){

 case "2":
  public void k(View v)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
      startActivity(i);
      
  }
 break;

 case "3":
  public void k(View v)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity3.class);
      startActivity(i);
      
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:-

String string = editText1.getText().toString();

       if(string.equals("2"))
       {
        Intent i = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(i); 
       }
       else if(equals("3"))
       {
        Intent i = new   Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity3.class); 
        startActivity(i);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the methods inside the switch-case

```
    case "2": 
    public void kden(View v) { 
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
         startActivity(i); 
    } 
    break;
```

and try this

```
 case "2":    
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(i); 
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, retrieve the value from the `EditText`. If you only want digits/numbers then you can set this in the properties for the`EditText`. For now, we'll leave it as accepting `string` values. Assuming the identifier for your `EditText` is 'editText1':

```
String targetActivity = editText1.getText().toString();
```

Secondly, you need to use conditional statements to evaluate which `Activity` to launch. @Sree used `switch-case` in his answer, here I will use `if` statements as they are much easier to read and understand.

```
Intent i;

if(targetActivity.equals("k")){
   i = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, StartSomeActivity.class);
   startActivity(i);
}

else if(targetActivity.equals("3")){
    i = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, StartAnotherActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Obviously you can change what values to compare against, I used `k` and `3` as those were the examples you gave in your question. Also be sure to swap out 'YourCurrentActivity' for the current Activity name and 'StartSomeActivity' and 'StartAnotherActivity' with the names of the desires activites you want to launch.

Comment: Have you correctly entered the name of the target activity?

Comment: Yes @scott target activity is the one to which I wanna move the screen to, right? They are two. MainActivity2 and MainActivity3.

Comment: And the current Activity is MainActivity?

Answer (score 0):

At least post the code properly in comment...

- Before using switch case with `String` read [Why can't I switch on a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/why-cant-i-switch-on-a-string)

And with value you can use this on your button click event

```
int key = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString());
Intent i;
switch (key) {
  case 1:
      i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class); 
    break;
  case 2:
      i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity3.class); 
    break;
}
startActivity(i);
```