# Activity context in switch case

Tags: android, android-activity, switch-statement

I want to use common progressBar which is used in all activities. This can be done by checking in if else statements like

```
if(mContext instanceOf ActivityA)
   {
     //Do Something   
   }else if(mContext instanceOf ActivityB)
   {
    //Do Something
   }
```

But I want to do Something like :

```
switch(mContext){
case mContext instaceOf ActivityA:
                    //Do Something
case mContext instanceOf ActivityB:
                    //DoSomething
}
```

How Can I Achive by checking context in switch

Comment: `switch` cannot be used for matching conditions, only values.

Comment: yes I want use progressBar which is common for all activities, i just have to pass context and value to it.

Comment: @sparta .  - so Is there any nice approach to check context rather than if else statements.

Comment: I think that `if/else`s are pretty fine in this case.

Comment: FWIW, there's probably a better way that a lengthy `if..else...` statements. It sounds as though you could, for instance, have a base `Activity` which `ActivityA` and `ActivityB` extends, and an `abstract` method that's called.

Comment: but you can still use switch without the conditions by extracting the class name as string from the context. Check my answer.

Comment: i also tried to use this method for string but it's not allowed in switch, but we can find switch case  support with string in jdk1.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can do it this way:**

```
String className = mContext.getClass().getSimpleName();

switch (className) {
  case "ActivityA":
     //Do Something
  case "ActivityB":
     //DoSomething
}
```

**Note:** String support for switch was added only after JDK 7. If you are using an earlier version of Java you can use a few hacks on the above to get switch working. Some examples in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/why-cant-i-switch-on-a-string).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a `switch` statement to match conditions.

> A switch works with the **byte**, **short**, **char**, and **int primitive data**
>   types. It also works with **enumerated types**,
>   the **String** class, and a few special classes that wrap certain
>   primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in
>   Numbers and Strings).