# Making the solving part of the calculator, pemdas sequence

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a GUI calculator. Everything seems good so far but how can I achieve the one like the built in windows calculator, where when you operate you see for ex. "100+2+9*4/8-3" so that whenever you click another + - / * button it will get solved in sequence. Pemdas? I think. I can manage to make the calculator function like that but it will only solve it in-order sequence because I only store 2 values, so I was wondering how I can store values of all current operations and their operator(+-/*)

Comment: See also this [calculator example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556).  It uses `ScriptEngine` to evaluate the expression in the text field.

Comment: Ohh a built in evaluator thanks for the new info!

Comment: You're welcome. :) Of course, if the point of your programming exercise is to understand **how to** do that process yourself, the script engine will be irrelevant. But if the main point is just to evaluate the expression, that'd be my 'go to' method. Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so I was wondering how I can store values of all current operations and their operator(+-/*)

Well, you could try storing each operation in an `ArrayList`, and place each operation in a class called `Operation` which has 3 variables `number1`, `number2` and `operation` which could be an `enum` or a `String` value. I'd prefer the enum approach but I'm leaving that to you.

So, you could have this class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PemdasSample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList <Operation> operations = new ArrayList<Operation>();
        operations.add(new Operation(5, 5, "SUM"));
        operations.add(new Operation(2, 2, "REST"));
        operations.add(new Operation(3, 4, "MULTIPLY"));

        for (Operation operation : operations) {
            switch (operation.getOperation()) {
                case "SUM":
                    System.out.println(operation.getNumber1() + operation.getNumber2());
                    break;
                case "REST":
                    System.out.println(operation.getNumber1() - operation.getNumber2());
                    break;
                case "MULTIPLY":
                    System.out.println(operation.getNumber1() * operation.getNumber2());
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Operation not found");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static class Operation {
        int number1;
        int number2;
        String operation;

        public Operation(int number1, int number2, String operation) {
            this.number1 = number1;
            this.number2 = number2;
            this.operation = operation;
        }

        public int getNumber1() {
            return number1;
        }

        public void setNumber1(int number1) {
            this.number1 = number1;
        }

        public int getNumber2() {
            return number2;
        }

        public void setNumber2(int number2) {
            this.number2 = number2;
        }

        public String getOperation() {
            return operation;
        }

        public void setOperation(String operation) {
            this.operation = operation;
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces this output:

```
10
0
12
```

You can take the logic (and separate the `Operation` class to be in its own file and not as an inner class as I did, not being static, etc.) and modify your program...

You didn't provide any code, so, if this approach doesn't work for you, explain why and provide a valid [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your issue.

### Disclaimer

This code sample requires Java 7 to work because of the String switch, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/338230/2180785) for more information.

I also didn't add the PEMDAS logic into the program as OP didn't provide any code, just helping with an idea on how to store operations.

Comment: Hello, I managed to solve my problem, I learned about infix to postfix notation then evaluating it XD thanks for the help bro!