# How to use strings as the same as inputting int?

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DaysInMonth
{
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter a year:")
  int year = input.nextInt();    enter code here
  System.out.print("Enter a month:"); 
  int month = input.nextInt();    enter code here
  int days = 0;       
  boolean isLeapYear = (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)||(year % 400 == 0);       

  switch (month){ 
  case 1: 
  days = 31; 

  break; 
  case 2: 
  if (isLeapYear) 
  days = 29; 
  else 
  days = 28; 

  break; 
  case 3: 
  days = 31; 
  break; 

 case 4: 
 days = 30; 
 break; 

 case 5: 
 days = 31; 
 break; 

 case 6: 
 days = 30; 
 break; 

  case 7: 
  days = 31; 
  break; 

  case 8 
  days = 31; 
  break; 

 case 9: 
 days = 30; 
 break; 

 case 10: 
 days = 31; 
 break; 

 case 11: 
 days = 30; 
 break; 

 case 12: 
 days = 31; 
 break; 
 default: 

String response = "Have a Look at what you've done and try again";
System.out.println(response); 
 System.exit(0); 
} 
  String response = "There are " +days+ " Days in Month "+month+ " of Year "   +year+ ".\n"; 
  System.out.println(response); // new line to show the result to the screen. 
}
```

}

Why can't I type in January to get the same output result if I type 1? It should print "There are 31 days in the month of January of Year 2018" I initialized the month so it should read January or any other month.

I know I have int but I am wondering how can I also use January for 1 to get the same output.

Comment: Use a `HashMap` with the `Integer` as the key and the `String` as the value

Comment: @GBlodgett or an array.

Comment: Indenting your code properly will make it more readable and people will be more likely to read it.

Comment: do you want to use a String variable in your switch() ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I use switch statement on a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/why-cant-i-use-switch-statement-on-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Strings in a switch statement to check for several equivalent cases:

```
switch (monthInput.toLowerCase()) {
    case "january":
    case "jan":
    case "1":
        days = 31;
        break;

    case "february":
    case "feb":
    case "2":
        days = isLeapYear ? 29 : 28;
        break;

    case "march":
    case "mar":
    case "3":
        days = 31;
        break;

    // etc.

    default:
        System.out.println(monthInput + " is not a valid month");
        input.close();
        System.exit(0);
}
```

But this means you have to read your input as a `String`, not as an `int`...

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a year:");
int year = input.nextInt();     // enter code here
input.nextLine(); // read the rest of the line (if any)

System.out.print("Enter a month:");
String monthInput = input.nextLine();
```

Note the use of `input.nextLine();` after the `.nextInt()` — this is because the `nextInt()` call does not consume all of the input, it *only* reads the int that you typed for the Year, it does *not* read the newline (enter key), so you have to read that to be ready to read the *next* input, which is the month number or name.

Comment: I'll take your advice into consideration!

Answer (score 0):

> I know I have int but I am wondering how can I also use January for 1 to get the same output.

A simple approach is to use name array

```
// before main.
static final String[] MONTH = "?,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec".split(",");

// inside main
String monthStr = MONTH[month];
```

Add the full month names as needed.