# building skills: difference between Java and C#?

Tags: c#, java, eclipse, visual-studio-2010

So this may seem like a general question..but for learning a programming language quickly and effectively, is C# or Java the way to go? (I prefer VS2010)

Is there some sort of site that will help a junior in college more efficiently gain understanding of these languages?

Thanks...just looking for some input

-DS

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295224/what-are-major-differences-between-c-and-java

Comment: Appreciate all the responses, lots of help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by my point of view (mainly a microsoft developer and a java beginner) it's not just a matter of preferences, the two languages are quite similar, yet i've always found harder to set up a development environment with java than with c#. In both eclipse and netbeans you have to choose the server (in web development for example), choose the libraries and configure all the enviroment and the ide and so on. For a beginner who wishes to learn "quickly" microsoft might be better . About tutorial, there's plenty of them , visit the home pages of the product and you'll surely find a good tutorial (asp.net, sun jsf, or whatever you wish to learn ) , if you need to start learnig from the ground i suggest to buy a book (there's plenty of them too) , i loved think in java and wrox professional c#

Comment: Back in Uni that was exactly the reason I did not get into Java.. I was too used to single cpp exes, and the whole "project" setup seemed overly complicated when I just wanted to compile/run a class (thus the little I did was with simpler/smaller ides that allowed single class compiling).  When I tried C# Express, it was really easy to start, I just said I wanted a console app and it created the file with my main :P. Of course, it still was a project setup, but I didnt have to worry about it, and  with time I got to learn how it worked, but it was too late, I had turned into a (happy)C# guy :)

Answer (score 9):

If you prefer VS2010 the answer seems obvious: C#

Answer (score 3):

Here's an article comparing C# and Java: http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html

If you prefer Visual Studio, then just start learning C#.

Answer (score 1):

Here must be answer with Java)

If you like learning something completely  different then java would be your choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn Java, then

- Joshua Bloch (he's worked on today's standards of the Java Collections Framework) - [Effective Java. Programming Language Guide.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/). [Google Books](http://books.google.co.za/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&dq=Joshua+Bloch+-+Effective+Java&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=CACqTKCqPIH98AbRiNXvDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q&f=false).

But since you prefer VS 2010, do C#.

Answer (score 1):

I should go for Java with NetBeans or Eclipse as IDE. I don't know what is wrong with VS2010 but everytime I want to use it, my opinion is that it doesn't works that good. Learning Java in combination of one of the two IDE's I suggested, is very interesting because of the IDE. They are a kind of magic: they know exactly if your code is correct or not before compilation. And they can even suggest you solutions to solve the error.

And if you like drawing GUI's, NetBeans is what you need! And everything you've made in Java can be executed everywhere (on each platform).

Java is one big logical language. Once you understand how object oriented programming works, you will see that everything is that logic. Nothing seems "magic" anymore.

Comment: I'm ok with Java, but seriously, if you want to draw guis, VS is waaaay better to do forms and stuff with their editors, than trying to use Swing or so.. at least the last graphical editors that I tried were still pretty far from VS's editor.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you understand the concepts behind the programming language paradigm, any of the options has a quit fast learning curve.

In my opinion Java is easier to learn, but C# has some features that make development faster.

Answer (score 1):

Either way is good, they are pretty similar(syntax wise, imo) and both are popular. Can't go wrong

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, C# would be the best choice as its easy to understand, practice and earns more than java...

Answer (score 0):

Both C# and Java are well thought out languages with well supported IDEs. That said, I prefer Java for it's excellent cross platform support and terrific API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest Java. Its a language thats supports by Oracle, HP, IBM, Sun etc. That and I don't want any competition in .Net