# Abstract/Virtual Functions in java

Tags: java, virtual, abstract

I've heard that all Java functions are implicitly virtual, but I'm still not sure if this will run how I want.

Suppose I have a class A, with child B.
both A and B have functions called foo(), so B's definition is overriding A's.

Suppose also that A has a function called that takes an instance of A as a parameter:

If I pass in an instance of B to the function, which definition of foo() will it call, A's or B's?

Comment: i think private functions are not virtual, you can have two `private foo()` methods and each class will call its own

Comment: @hoaz they are indeed virtual but can't be overridden. By the way, in the subclass you don't override the `private` method instead you just *hide* it. This is known as hiding. More info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: don't you think you contradict to yourself? :) if it is virtual, what virtual properties does it have?

Comment: @hoaz http://stackoverflow.com/q/4547453/1065197 by the way, don't ask me why Java was designed that way, ask James Gosling about it :)

Comment: that says the same thing, private methods are final and thus non-virtual

Comment: The word `private` is not mentioned in the question - anywhere! Come on guys!!!!

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon  Nor is any other access level -- and the answer depends on the access level.

Comment: It should be A.foo() due to polymorphism of passing object of type B as type A in the method parameter.
If you want B.foo() to be invoked, you should cast the passed parameter as B then invoke, or you should changed the parameter type from class A to an interface defining foo() that A implements, where B extends A. Then whatever implementation of the interface is passed will have its' foo() method invoked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment private functions are not virtual and I want to demonstrate it using following example:

```
class A {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("A#foo()");
    }

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("A#bar()");
        qux();
    }

    private void qux() {
        System.out.println("A#qux()");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("B#foo()");
    }

    private void qux() {
        System.out.println("B#qux()");
    }
}
```

Now lets run following code:

```
A foobar = new B();
foobar.foo(); // outputs B#foo() because foobar is instance of B
foobar.bar(); // outputs A#bar() and A#qux() because B does not have method bar 
              // and qux is not virtual
```

Comment: private methods are limited to the scope of the class.
protected, to the package
public, everyone

Therefore, a private member of a class has no external accessibility, even for inherited classes, therefore, it being virtual serves no purpose as it can't be accessed by anything other than it's containing class.

Answer (score 3):

B's implementation will be called.
That's exactly what `virtual` means.

Comment: Virtual means it can be inherited or overridden.